# Q​u​i​n​e R​e​l​a​y​!

Tags: quine, answer-chaining

## Quine Relay!

A quine relay of order \$n\$ is a series of programs \$P_1\dots P_n\$ in **distinct** languages such that each program \$P_i\$ outputs \$P_{i+1}\$ and \$P_n\$ outputs \$P_1\$.

For example, a 2-quine relay can be seen here:

#### Ruby → Perl 6:

[This Ruby program](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X8XOxkapoCgzr0RBQ4mrQEHDxTHEUa8oNTFFy0hTLzkjsahYLzexQEPNKr8oRZMLrBwkYKWglpxRpKmXlZ@Zp8TFFR/v6ucSH89FZeP@/wcA):

```rb
$><<"print ("
p (DATA.read*2).chars.map(&:ord)
$><<".map: &chr).join"

__END__
$><<"print ("
p (DATA.read*2).chars.map(&:ord)
$><<".map: &chr).join"

__END__
```

outputs [this Perl 6 program](https://tio.run/##7VDLDgIhDLz7FZyMJmRDF@iCv2I8GGPiGl03xP/HdqFc1JNXD1OaYTp9zOd0w5znNE5Ptdlb1Ap7gimwTiuAngNnxnNmOJDQEu9EZKpQSAwEkgdXXofNBLSKAyckcyT3/EKRxMgfrioWPUi1iUJLY@rhAxPQzKsXz/NpmXcjNuCh2ax1X8xkJjAoPdoB2s6E6AuQqodQVhfu2xz/o/501MOqux/nnVqfLmnbXR/jlPML):

```
print ([36, 62, 60, 60, 34, 112, 114, 105, 110, 116, 32, 40, 34, 10, 112, 32, 40, 68, 65, 84, 65, 46, 114, 101, 97, 100, 42, 50, 41, 46, 99, 104, 97, 114, 115, 46, 109, 97, 112, 40, 38, 58, 111, 114, 100, 41, 10, 36, 62, 60, 60, 34, 46, 109, 97, 112, 58, 32, 38, 99, 104, 114, 41, 46, 106, 111, 105, 110, 34, 10, 10, 95, 95, 69, 78, 68, 95, 95, 10, 36, 62, 60, 60, 34, 112, 114, 105, 110, 116, 32, 40, 34, 10, 112, 32, 40, 68, 65, 84, 65, 46, 114, 101, 97, 100, 42, 50, 41, 46, 99, 104, 97, 114, 115, 46, 109, 97, 112, 40, 38, 58, 111, 114, 100, 41, 10, 36, 62, 60, 60, 34, 46, 109, 97, 112, 58, 32, 38, 99, 104, 114, 41, 46, 106, 111, 105, 110, 34, 10, 10, 95, 95, 69, 78, 68, 95, 95, 10]
.map: &chr).join
```

which in turn outputs the original Ruby program.

## The challenge

The first answer will be an order \$1\$ quine relay: a normal quine. It can be in any language.

The next answer will choose a different language and create an order \$2\$ quine relay using those two languages.

And so on. The \$k\$-th answer will create an order \$k\$ quine relay using the previous \$k - 1\$ languages and a new, different language.

### Winning

If, after 2 weeks, no more answers have been added, the winner is the person who answered with the highest-order quine relay.

### More rules

- No person may answer twice in a row.
- No person may answer within an hour of their most recent post.
- Languages which differ by version are considered distinct. Thus, Python 2 and Python 3 can both be part of the chain.
- Languages which differ by compiler or interpreter are **not** considered distinct. So, [Python 3 (Cython)](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM9ZNBtP/gQAA) and [Python 3](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/4PBAA) are considered *interchangeable* but not distinct.
- Each answer may order the languages in any way. If the third answer has an order of Ruby → Perl 6 → JavaScript, you are not restricted to appending a language to the end. If you were adding Java to the mix, then you could write JavaScript → Ruby → Java → Perl 6 if you so desired.

### Format for answers

> ## n. Language<sub>1</sub> → Language<sub>2</sub> → … → Language<sub>n</sub>
>
> ### Language<sub>1</sub>
>
> ```
> language 1 code
> ```
>
> ### Language<sub>2</sub>
>
> ```
> language 2 code
> ```
>
> ### Language<sub>3</sub>
>
> ```
> language 3 code
> ```
>
> …
>
> ### Language<sub>n</sub>
>
> ```
> language n code
> ```

Feel free to add explanations anywhere in your answers.

Comment: You should add something like a 2 character minimum to prevent degenerate quine chains such as the empty string. Also, something to prevent languages that by default echo output their input. Alternatively, you can roll these into one by requiring that all outputs in the chain must be unique.

Comment: @YonatanN Actually once enough languages get added it would be hard to pull that off... would be interesting to see someone try. Although I think all so far have empty quines.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen as of now, someone can trash the question by using a Bubblegum-type language and an empty input.

Comment: @YonatanN Hm yeah I guess there are too many ways to abuse it. (Also this kind of thing is why other answer chaining questions give the win to the *second* last answer.)

Comment: @YonatanN 0 or 1 character quines usually do not meet our standard definition of quine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## 10. Javascript → Foo → brainfuck → Wumpus → Gol><> → RAD → ><> → Python 2 → Brain-Flak → 4

Edit: For the next answer, I've golfed how the Python generates the Brain-Flak a bit more [here](https://tio.run/##jVTLbuM2FN3rK1jbGJOhJb/dkRUZk5nCHRQoareLLgKjoWXKUsOQMkXNKDW87Qf0E/sj6dUjlp3ZVIDE@zj33BehLUujlxepdhw5sUwy45hYoQX6iX1haaDjxPySGWuXITt6Y@urxPRDpYr32gXhS6WauFopA7aaxTLMgsdGqv3oFvV3/EtfZkIAw9nd8FyZdLZ9RiXl1@wpydL6cPT2CgdMv5eOhqbRk2cTKTmuaPZKhHEa9VMdvMpO8tyggan1oxKL2wUorZrr0lKyaLbr/3r3AwqzSx/EgrEpoVau8pfJX7NWgCLlm3yvahV61gG5Ki1NjkZvBh8xGPzHQvoMUgNB9h0wlI5QsIuRX5muyp3A3jNd1HqJKVef6cvdVxoPIoVay1gygTRPM2HmLStg5gywBJP7jO156uPmNllwN6zzPq1qGVY92ZYFY7JapdSqekGjllXWYy@hIGtCysTVp6rBhqG1UcsKlUYYx8hHAw/FcPk6x/a5hPsPmxNYKSXE2ikLwROH6Dt0jzoxsvkBDdDGQybiEpVOeM7k6N@//wH@whbG1pWrc2wydOLNCbaqJK8Ks9r/u6I2lNQ@E0M33/KW7hgBfdegR6m@ogheo9CeS66Z4UXxSMTysWCT/OUFh/4f/uJ48HHg/2Z0LPdOqNXTp4jpT/B3IHjsEm/tB3g8Id4WTndGvNwfeIGSqRLcEWqP1/TecZyHznF9cl36zvt@ejO0xWj@3n6nPujkc@d4OMFLDyedJAt1u@Mhkjgn871QW7gZwtN@QhMa0iVd0QPFCV2RGyzsnNA1XRVLyG8F4iLlqMHVqNwWhK484eee5ibTEmmv22XdbuIHkcaTAfFWlTQk3qGU3GHZUyGNiReW0nAE4rIWpwT4Jl4C8zCwHNIjN9NRLzUaE@dPFUv8xBIse8VXsKftjqF8rvQOWrIn79/iakQw7xy3p9lgUBwUF6DAdl3i/BXGQuARoYXDdacVojYPB6RoP1i4btV/GfcmqA4hvfuHahOw1c4xPBFMHjZOUUPgLwInqJd6ZzAh9GFDyP18bg83dWLXnZUshPSqliezWpgOiw3WVClQ4cmYOJonnBn8MzMROHJs5zS9ytEbQBrATr/F5jbO/Wv0GT4j9fACMALaBBHuO8dhbzQdn/r7sxNGQ9eEFF3@Bw), but I can't be bothered to update the links.

Added Gol><>. It's just a short `rpH` after the Wumpus code. I've also optimised the brainfuck and Brain-Flak code somewhat. 
[Verification!](https://tio.run/##jVTdkps2FL7nKVTsiaXI4P9tMIsnm3ScTGc6xe1FLzyeGmMwdLUIC5Gw9fg2D9BH7ItsD4IF27kpHsT5@fSdT@dovPOy6OUl4fsAmXGS5tKUMUcL9LP3xct8Eafy11xq@xwZ0U1swFM5CDkv3@sUbF9y3u6rHbVhJ7w4CXP/sbXqPLpHg33wZZDkjAFDk255rkIi3z0jRfk1f0rzrP6YYneFA6Y/VKKlaf30WUY8mVQ0B87COIsGmfBfbTN9btHApH/ibHG/AEevuS4jikV4@8FvDz@hML/MwV4IthJq56q@Kv5atQKUJW/qvbrV1sYHpKsibY3WbxsfedD4D6X1GawWgowHYFCJkHkXLb8KXcmdwtxzUWq9xKjR5@Jy9pUX@BFH@jJOPIZEkOVMznXN92QD0JiXHHLvEGQObm@TBndDa@apVcPQ6s7qGrRJ05WlV2dBY11TeowlCNKmRBWulkqDAU3rIF0LuUAYx8hBQxvFcPm6p04jYf1@c4YopYRoe64heOIQ/YDWqBsjIziiIdrYSEZBglQSnoYc/fvtH@AvY2GsXaW6p7ZCN96cYao8CTSto/R1/rekDmjqNMxwnO@JVTpGwN@T6DHhX1EEr@ToECSB8GRQqkcsTh5LNhDx8oJD509ncTo62Hd@lyJODmYo@NPHyBMf4f@B4IlF7JXj48mU2Dv4WnfELpyh7fMk4ywwGT/gFV2bprntnlZny6Jv7B9nb0cGG8/fGW/4e5F@7p6OZ3jp8SzSdMHv90GIElyQ@YHxHdwNZgsnpSkN6ZK69EhxSl3yFjOjIHRF3XIMxT1DAcsC1OJqVGEwQl2bOYUtApmLBAm71/N6vdTxI4GnQ2K7lTUi9lFZ1kidqbQmxA6VNRqDuazNGQG@qZ1CP6Sq@Ppzm9etVZTrre/2MykwMf/icYKfvBQn/XJl3tNu76FizsUeTm9M393iaoQ/755257vhsPxQXIJ8w7KI@XcYM4bHhJYJy5pViDo8GpKyU/7CsqpWqX03m@otpL/eVkODC9A9hWeCyXZjlhp8Z@Gbfj3/B4kJodsNIev53Bht6sKWdadYCOl3TyVNL60eN3XdcHmzuBfx3kaddku35Y041zUzqImnE2KKIA08iX/xZASJAhsFza7E9IegB7Cz77GFgQvnGt3A70jdZR@CgJZ@hAfmadQfzybnwaFJQg/pipCyHf8B)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org)

```javascript
(f=_=>{q=(c=String.fromCharCode)(39);Q=c(34);b=c(96);x=0;console.log(Q+[...`${Q}99+&;75*1-l2:8-&o@rpH${q}${q+q}rpp>o<def n(x):global l;r=p+p+f+F+P+q+(p+P)*(l-x)+Q+P if x<l else p+p+f+F+P+(p+P)*(x-l)+P;l=x;return r;''a''p=chr(40);P=chr(41);q=chr(91);Q=chr(93);f=chr(123);F=chr(125);l=4;print p+p+p+p+p+p+P+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+P+f+F+P,str().join(map(n,map(lambda x:ord(x)-48,str().join(map(lambda c:${b}600${b}+(str(c-99).zfill(2)+${b}99500${b}.zfill(10) if c>99 else str(c).zfill(2)+${b}500${b}),[`+[...`(f=${f})()`].map(c=>c.charCodeAt())+`]))[::-1]+${b}99996${b}))),${[...'pppppppPpPPfFpPPfFpPPfFpPPfFPppPpPPfFpPP'].join`+`}${q}`].map(s=>c(43).repeat(Math.max(-x+s.charCodeAt(),0))+c(45).repeat(Math.max(x-(x=s.charCodeAt()),0))+c(46)).join(c()).match(/.{1,253}/g).join(c(10)+Q))})()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVLbjpswEP0VHqLFswYv5NY1XketVor2pZKjPkZRIQ4kWTngGFqhIr49NYSm3RTL42HmzO3Y78nPpJTmqCs/L3bp5YIy/p0vmjNHkn@rzDHfk8wUp9dDYl4tANCEAltxiSZTYFt70jmwmgdMFnlZqJSoYo9WeE0IiUfNqqUUP7BPs8fQV@Po2X8oPhv9NmrOrd343BqtF8XLLs2cHNUQ7VWxTZSjmOEaa5zhJRb4jJHGAh6R8mvAKyycY@bUL8pJVZk6f3EDqvYVYMEUr5lJqx8mdwxz3cR1NZcHg6YBMHHVQmDnXqNhP1OnTYBlvRaOrboc1BnYfFOmLR9VX/HPErcthi46ef8vvLIyCMh7cczRKdEo9zqpktN2lzh1VJidnd6fPt/jBoSMRs22nQdBd2DUgaRPKZBf2VEpNAbcOSidXRGDOQygY0ouKL1S1cfdBQ0h4K3j66XZBzBqshYQxBvS9SD5QhI53P@XCgHgeAOwjiI/3AyFKZ33WQC8UdOlcfX1E1qIbHknxD92d9NPG@O4exHtULO0NdF0AsSkOk0q9DWpDtZRI7/G5YdmvMD2Y7Gz/7G1j2r@EX2Dz2FgWVqjRVfygJ5IE3rj2aR92t@clkO8AujouFx@Aw)

## [Foo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Foo)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5V1HcuM4FN37GN6y@I41277/ymNlhPcTAgnJ7Kp2WaaInzOB//79@/n53swL0ufYs@v2K78b9xvSryD729Z3FbA4r6/vHOYSwgLS/isKJpqWgB99@1ZgHPo36Bp4hRmUvnO/aR1c/u1DrpHkjYgYQX8mXNsoeikARkD@@n7cjwo2ZM/GXKAPpShS9A/gHk6TE5jcXweaeRBARR/dEONIoR9lcK@mD2uZNQxd6@qc0C/8I/DDai4kc3xwew2cwcgJVPz6xu6PEfeDg4QhnEbc8i/o5FH@ZPlWl/CvHOdhCixW0Psm/rvVe1fC7/Tf@2f4S4X7usdcIeXpL5G0Cv/e4i9xXCLvXMET9uAUFkF9yq3SgL3Ta1PuYx3PDV59GgVIUPiBUwmCSIgAx1otug9WwpXAgxv34bi1CH@FG/YobnM0YQp1otyHjEsDnbCfLAUi@iKeUAHFFCGYRpEI9yGVuA0y4FT1VpG4VnoNQh8Ql9SNr9assHwUVIh6o743zw@tqG/lbHUALOE6/2dRphR@vJ0Ed1XYD@ryrNo7SNF/V8w6nuXm/kIVqoGU9KK/LvZdkAf8/ltJdajN8XlS7ZSMrqhvAew7FSTRfURGony91Z6iQJb9ZFH8wNynI@qjXMKsuvacyYA24cen0MzHfaiVvqTcP6RbfGCjOFrpbVbgIQ3ZCf39GS3tB4hZ8QIzMOi013Sqc32LPUoPHuivbbGn2R5B9zHF0PQWcsPFQ7MpRSx/49zmYJM9Pgg7IePLJRX8z/MHfPFwP4OGWyBU8TFVTZA0FOPNVrQkvCeypreN8eq8itj0xPyLTQQiYBSB6eMNUwbx5iW8x9vd6XU207S2CP@hGjzXtDLhH2lavbhilrN4/fewh2ks/uI@UtQ3cX6FcAb04zzeTzri90@Sbqz1xBIHIZCwAcv/8Pvz8TZHlZW8gNyKsQ1UKczj3orMNYJgi@QckZYFCBC1JKCwYDuFPrH8Fa/Jlwg88goloAVVCG8d7AbjJ4R0CPzeilS56cvjBI8wiQLox6BUlAD0Bd8QVYVLnT8Cv5R7ggw2hXB4eVrTECilE5tEnPuFvOZaDK7pgioSyJjESzZAfghZEB6eyVJ9GWmGIEnCNzY60xT7mIXM4HVByXEoeKF4hia8r1qfaERAp45axA8UJjIUCmIONCOPWjhVSXp@/HiBHXJZFtzMK2srJMpFuHI1mt/bULM/c@NBAQLSFqcuOYFHwhKg@ia@qocKlCok7AJ3Zle/73XSdXyS4MasJjFGxMRLLkIwohXtAhaz5Mgz5vfEPoY@lZSw1U90g2KUVRu6mv1E2qRbXlEfYy0xfJW9Ne4tfEhAI/gjK2mCE2gKyNXy87AT1sIWd4k9dkm@AT72dqqXAnqx/DyBcei5HKlFyER0JhBRQQIeuolKTF@D0iyiMr3a8GxyOZIwUxuIaMfjEXTKt2ZRq7VJjw8sjAysIZQIUImsUF6gPT0eA@iKLbgPEPTLQXoeXcKoL0gus/2xcljjT7/zCkdGnWSwzUzVaRjulmAzG5VkeSC2Fa6/ji@E7aZUBxCJarx1vjFoStWLfKxxAqqD60gjcEZW6NaLUTG2Mjd4OIoq71JgUBa60c1nHK/AHSTIK71C6SHIfn1yj9OBGRvVeMDjbM16/MX0CU5YjBQ748SFbnkKvz8v68ivjnhg7O6L5T830R29/JCYfymM5i3/Cnp7AIArCw30EQVz7iu8P@0vzF5BtWGdt2TnaTEqHUMze4RF4iEApGFPuJzjKgvG@3J5vdXKpewSDOQi6E34Ve85onKLTehwMGdPmwlz9OuK/mwNW1S/0qD3bcTbHO0Q21SkVXPbqFZoIAqwyy1E1ubWKsEBQMeBmXq1nPuY77z0mQhnYzY@2wFOz2e@L47ZaIVwtaNvFjTp8EdLG6BdWDLLH2iM2@MeO95AD4qtS563LyMTRl8/UG1kLchnkyvY4XGO1qFXjia3gF4JL46I2s1hMJ/FGiabeZvjXSyWzws7rE8W85/lh2tSYQ8NXGmzUlL2er3/cTbHwfNbmzFqrBUGvXM2tU7UDEiLXfZkKYKEr1regdG@KXF@KV5suMU9p20HcYpY@MvbE6eN71GfOH2ZK7LuAPwlGncPu1GufB2LpMe3@6er9D/RsB0eaRYwmeoviPA3RLgNMTFO9y63keYGLxSGdN58cGA0gP1ehD2Ob9iTprQgHLhVewr3j6xg7lrw1/QdveRKCz7QDywZYPHy0lHqfsOS3pGfeOwzqogqu9B7whtwusNnvuWsZX5Aybjf0ZrZJETGRZLOSSTfuMb9SDL3C3zaMDUNGtVg1R06lvToWCALrG9tjnlZCO8B2bOf7HtwlHKCmcazxXlwrnFGpgFe6gxN1/qTlQHK60pmelQ3M31vqLydqpvu19eovK5Bbt/3hLdV@nVcolv2Du@H6LhP7fPhlsXUHq0gxaLI5yvMnc34BswH4NNYESz8fl8dTuhMwVv9o4UCvbcFY1RXcx5ZOPjw@2KZhL9bIb8/vcJciF8Uk3x/XDMx/Cqa@VG0isX0bCOXvHFN2@kxbSeGm0@teYIhS2h7ds3efwzBTe6aN8aBuDVOfNuijzquglr@06A5HBZ7v76Ppsy0LcrXpIx3t8Y/ckSJaPoO2Bx/EkUiW@O37tb4IceYBE5key@@@q6a@3/qeJqg8H/aAS1xx/dRB7QM2aD@fQ9oOVf3T/cvZanzT8R6ku4vc1zQUZqYof/HDuOrdD9wosDXz8//)

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7V3bjhMxDH3nV6qefwIkJITEAxLfvwiWbifJsWMnTpNpM0iLtjuT2I6vx2775dfn7z@//f764@3tUr0gvY5rcr3/yu/G/xuOjyD526XvymjxXDisgYKfftLaiUTTFuZd6jcCccy/04aO8xmqDOZd8PffNeSKFG6fDQykKowuhUAfyfj4icweMIpqzJUnHnpymKYjWEhfMYkCNK6LQMqwlkOLNMBHKgfMqyGIQyzk5waEDYTujDFsxOabqyYFIaeMqToVFG3y/71J@olzuh2vF4nXO0LOjlBYgBZzhMSkQh3TBBRTQaHEEm4uPjjbwTqRGhxZmoP1Yao44EkJMMTRgMGyEnEwc74iZ7h6ORujeqvJJl28QUo4G5dQycQQBVhKHhloXREC1mUiWzrEstEc0NDlTVBKGmOgj10Dblo2LWsXqZuvZ@RrvIxeuVe0Lu9bn7c@vxzvURkmXGNMJvS3p@hPapwkW1@qj6QCjYsVEViBkhNJDCqCd4DvQ5DkNZu9rXQhuKl6jvm4BJrA9tLbSz@/z4kHZ92gIB40koJgRxRvzA/3h6mOgv95/CAubiEHwXKEv0/fPC5xaAw@RKPPeyy4908HcLPYBB8crlAR9CsPzj2Hr90O1S8@PDRBuMttSIC4/7h5wSzrPizH3hgI0WMKzxwfQNHT/v/KoaNaWzHnQEgcLMzgWo7RoKg9Dq9nIxcoCpXbvYWIS/bANilOg24LECJKLUDmua6UemGMhL7nk1Ejr5@TmcmEnKvhqMHOEkLRA36vOt2XZgU2mxCWs9Ofm0gj7YekZhD1UnUJMo7k4uAeW6sOQCnH6wKie6eamlovuIULJkjoYrou2b68CNkQlhOTNRrCAGE2YKYS7X6ZJcfgeJ8ULBSu8kEji@KKrgN0VqhF8UApIgOcIG5Ac@woFVPVosymIEOt4K5d2VkRUKq8RXjRIh3JTdKw7VSeMtOQdKZ5QaI81l0tMqAyIUkWhACWpSZKUGa5IfJdMk0q8svSrUthQXCdheQcfrIeFsVMp2JHuRzqZicGPjGnKt1befRE06q3sJSfB4PEx9YCRxo3HLbAlyw0CUaiZUJYgonatrWTJT7YpPMV4tHBqqCcqFYb5aNyVuYREiHIkT9BIh66a3oCY1nIDohS@7MPdGq25kerLph5VKLfLk9dqLIGH9DeHI/5ukELIUNJQqEBBKigB1KQbF9WTmLsJSrHLwTZSKU4TbfNumsGE2yV7QxeL0r1D08OY8XvRjIp1XJhjAZjRMM4pjCT70jdwPAIBtWTE0rZXs61aH4SAaDPmlsiqeRkVKcBS3g1IOxC0B2VEy50i7v2WnxB5/aTS9no7bc4H7k9THWmox8ouHAblP7hdWHB/msuUUcy/Kk@1cy8MK0JeDQB9bhlgPv8/bUURa1VTHWABaYWEI@WEWgsLkK/ggV32hzYlvXyil0dyxBbTr42oEC53AhkjWoN3Z1Cpg0HHGJU@kxAVHPVZrgfdIjjMRq0rXbkqzAlrStbYP3B@uyVPa8P17OAxfWh0pd3oIhx3RrjKBx6dWhSO2eCu9t@Ki7unsLrEEHJA5JXdUoWpqmiyTNXl46BYOuETGkNHvGbtFllsWhaO0bxhuTzzSPL3H3rCZuiEnbAetpUcGrANbjXWiT6hiH9OmXrQKheBPooEezpOSx6LPCxfC7bkP1iekSxvdRP57iY4mjtj/5dAXkdt2qr8IjIMOi9YfiGjuN9fs2wjur4M50oaLQ5@4XVo4YPep8seeSFcHDWaJwgsg5bwPGGOm3gmSaIalpqThNzaXRsIKbQ8erC@zn1OU32HAwwza4ozCCBb5LQU5IEGK2pZNlGO8toTcPWtueE95Fs2@5CC85l7mglaUYzvYHvAG4akzVJsxosRugxwYrqUSBA71KhY6K0TP20Vp748QPNgWhFNQxrCbrfHFZ9KQJyvziutu9bafve7Oqq5YmM5mX0p3zBeSDNH0WDlg@jCSUhQrCblk3LpsVPy/6iiBVktL8sYZ/pPtN9pvtM95k@f2ze@c@2we1Xz3Cm/9b79Pb2Bw)

## [Wumpus](https://github.com/m-ender/wumpus)

```javascript
"99+&;75*1-l2:8-&o@rpH'''rpp>o<def n(x):global l;r=p+p+f+F+P+q+(p+P)*(l-x)+Q+P if x<l else p+p+f+F+P+(p+P)*(x-l)+P;l=x;return r;''a''p=chr(40);P=chr(41);q=chr(91);Q=chr(93);f=chr(123);F=chr(125);l=4;print p+p+p+p+p+p+P+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+P+f+F+P,str().join(map(n,map(lambda x:ord(x)-48,str().join(map(lambda c:`600`+(str(c-99).zfill(2)+`99500`.zfill(10) if c>99 else str(c).zfill(2)+`500`),[40,102,61,95,61,62,123,113,61,40,99,61,83,116,114,105,110,103,46,102,114,111,109,67,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,41,40,51,57,41,59,81,61,99,40,51,52,41,59,98,61,99,40,57,54,41,59,120,61,48,59,99,111,110,115,111,108,101,46,108,111,103,40,81,43,91,46,46,46,96,36,123,81,125,57,57,43,38,59,55,53,42,49,45,108,50,58,56,45,38,111,64,114,112,72,36,123,113,125,36,123,113,43,113,125,114,112,112,62,111,60,100,101,102,32,110,40,120,41,58,103,108,111,98,97,108,32,108,59,114,61,112,43,112,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,113,43,40,112,43,80,41,42,40,108,45,120,41,43,81,43,80,32,105,102,32,120,60,108,32,101,108,115,101,32,112,43,112,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,40,112,43,80,41,42,40,120,45,108,41,43,80,59,108,61,120,59,114,101,116,117,114,110,32,114,59,39,39,97,39,39,112,61,99,104,114,40,52,48,41,59,80,61,99,104,114,40,52,49,41,59,113,61,99,104,114,40,57,49,41,59,81,61,99,104,114,40,57,51,41,59,102,61,99,104,114,40,49,50,51,41,59,70,61,99,104,114,40,49,50,53,41,59,108,61,52,59,112,114,105,110,116,32,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,80,43,112,43,80,43,112,43,80,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,112,43,80,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,44,115,116,114,40,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,109,97,112,40,110,44,109,97,112,40,108,97,109,98,100,97,32,120,58,111,114,100,40,120,41,45,52,56,44,115,116,114,40,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,109,97,112,40,108,97,109,98,100,97,32,99,58,36,123,98,125,54,48,48,36,123,98,125,43,40,115,116,114,40,99,45,57,57,41,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,50,41,43,36,123,98,125,57,57,53,48,48,36,123,98,125,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,49,48,41,32,105,102,32,99,62,57,57,32,101,108,115,101,32,115,116,114,40,99,41,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,50,41,43,36,123,98,125,53,48,48,36,123,98,125,41,44,91,96,43,91,46,46,46,96,40,102,61,36,123,102,125,41,40,41,96,93,46,109,97,112,40,99,61,62,99,46,99,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,65,116,40,41,41,43,96,93,41,41,91,58,58,45,49,93,43,36,123,98,125,57,57,57,57,54,36,123,98,125,41,41,41,44,36,123,91,46,46,46,39,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,80,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,80,112,112,80,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,39,93,46,106,111,105,110,96,43,96,125,36,123,113,125,96,93,46,109,97,112,40,115,61,62,99,40,52,51,41,46,114,101,112,101,97,116,40,77,97,116,104,46,109,97,120,40,45,120,43,115,46,99,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,65,116,40,41,44,48,41,41,43,99,40,52,53,41,46,114,101,112,101,97,116,40,77,97,116,104,46,109,97,120,40,120,45,40,120,61,115,46,99,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,65,116,40,41,41,44,48,41,41,43,99,40,52,54,41,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,99,40,41,41,46,109,97,116,99,104,40,47,46,123,49,44,50,53,51,125,47,103,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,99,40,49,48,41,43,81,41,41,125,41,40,41]))[::-1]+`99996`))),p+p+p+p+p+p+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+P+p+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pRZdb9Mw8K9UPNCYuMiOPxI3DPGEeAzPCGllW2Eoa0O2iYo/P@7O5zTtmk0MtUnO5/N9f/j3/U13f/vw8CqE/HVdujd60RbLavF6@6HvPs3n877r3m/fXV6tZ5tsJ5bf2@23VTtr6/6sy7t8nX/Mm/xXnnV5I95k7WIn8s95M7tez3bv2tlVe3s129Mx1W7Riryp27Nd3V/d3febWV/P56v5vDu7@NFnVom6iZAW9S@CAkCfI2REvSZIFwB@ZNAJ4Gfrrr/e3JHE9GuGp2Et8H28buTtXZ@Jtz@315vsZtVlG4nvdnXz7XI12y23/SVYv7DVMR1TXCzPvVLneYbbF4sQxNs/6@u2zQqRn4fgYI8RWgn0zsX7EKJ76MSYHImF/GKV1KqQXsvg8O0LCRZLrQ2uYDcEBCpEeXgskDv44jEjrafThNYaYCAu4WNlKAmLK9pAeuBHLJ2WrkTYBVlpkh0SvmB8qEb4UjrLeF0oUqwiohC5ozbasaQqSvIRJJRBLiDJGhloK/6Dl8aTubAHwSVBJVIZYu8AA0dBJVDDET8H2sDb49pE9t6y/YUsi8QQ/YccR0u7xyZ6fNDhyEUNTkKPmoKswuiAwWh6RXYkm8A96GFYIaUidcnfmpiSrPhR9CkVviuVtLDkEqapSALaqYgX2hqlWsNuAxIS5AbtMA5qrwF7HqMAsCmeV2NCPgqOvrZJMtqmKB9wly0lkZSSJfszqgggUBj6g4siQI6mdMLcRBpMqwLTiNNQnd4PKe1iPRwRlHuCIY8P951ODNQJDeC0U3uaUk2SmIEN@QFUc4FTaFSR4I7Hnn/ik/JhasGoEyk0Rr3gCKIs16wfTOWq9Vy1bigBFWI/iRmi4@FDpOKCoM6BlYSxj2nquA2Qp8Y1BXmGjvT/ocuEWIghSOXixx1sLpbS7RidKuFAfKCGw@0oqlIUsdUqxz2uohRLZXoki05i1pySOMkNs5kq4rDWcQQUzHOq2B@p/xKtJ/TVGCBo3NCvH3fw/QBLvRbl8TGSA0SBR9U4dnGweTIPWYUn5paP5nFixEESudIyUH921DnBh8FMRqTkYfbYQs12pp2RlSYM0@LUU6n0qaIvyhchmM3zHE0Y/HlYHhwffzz5cDkRBEycfRSo58Z2aP2oy8eco1MUhLJMCwzZiGlBNZrmlyH2/xZbyxXAQR6UMv@rFA82hmhOu3/Puyn1bEKebFqRbkQRkqosHXfLWLCGuoDlqePixciW8Rb1jIDUPvjaQP9xKX4V4styudBf8bYagj8XQsjxNfrwEv001Jymnz88/AU)

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish)

```javascript
"rpH'''rpp>o<def n(x):global l;r=p+p+f+F+P+q+(p+P)*(l-x)+Q+P if x<l else p+p+f+F+P+(p+P)*(x-l)+P;l=x;return r;''a''p=chr(40);P=chr(41);q=chr(91);Q=chr(93);f=chr(123);F=chr(125);l=4;print p+p+p+p+p+p+P+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+P+f+F+P,str().join(map(n,map(lambda x:ord(x)-48,str().join(map(lambda c:`600`+(str(c-99).zfill(2)+`99500`.zfill(10) if c>99 else str(c).zfill(2)+`500`),[40,102,61,95,61,62,123,113,61,40,99,61,83,116,114,105,110,103,46,102,114,111,109,67,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,41,40,51,57,41,59,81,61,99,40,51,52,41,59,98,61,99,40,57,54,41,59,120,61,48,59,99,111,110,115,111,108,101,46,108,111,103,40,81,43,91,46,46,46,96,36,123,81,125,57,57,43,38,59,55,53,42,49,45,108,50,58,56,45,38,111,64,114,112,72,36,123,113,125,36,123,113,43,113,125,114,112,112,62,111,60,100,101,102,32,110,40,120,41,58,103,108,111,98,97,108,32,108,59,114,61,112,43,112,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,113,43,40,112,43,80,41,42,40,108,45,120,41,43,81,43,80,32,105,102,32,120,60,108,32,101,108,115,101,32,112,43,112,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,40,112,43,80,41,42,40,120,45,108,41,43,80,59,108,61,120,59,114,101,116,117,114,110,32,114,59,39,39,97,39,39,112,61,99,104,114,40,52,48,41,59,80,61,99,104,114,40,52,49,41,59,113,61,99,104,114,40,57,49,41,59,81,61,99,104,114,40,57,51,41,59,102,61,99,104,114,40,49,50,51,41,59,70,61,99,104,114,40,49,50,53,41,59,108,61,52,59,112,114,105,110,116,32,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,80,43,112,43,80,43,112,43,80,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,112,43,80,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,44,115,116,114,40,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,109,97,112,40,110,44,109,97,112,40,108,97,109,98,100,97,32,120,58,111,114,100,40,120,41,45,52,56,44,115,116,114,40,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,109,97,112,40,108,97,109,98,100,97,32,99,58,36,123,98,125,54,48,48,36,123,98,125,43,40,115,116,114,40,99,45,57,57,41,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,50,41,43,36,123,98,125,57,57,53,48,48,36,123,98,125,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,49,48,41,32,105,102,32,99,62,57,57,32,101,108,115,101,32,115,116,114,40,99,41,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,50,41,43,36,123,98,125,53,48,48,36,123,98,125,41,44,91,96,43,91,46,46,46,96,40,102,61,36,123,102,125,41,40,41,96,93,46,109,97,112,40,99,61,62,99,46,99,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,65,116,40,41,41,43,96,93,41,41,91,58,58,45,49,93,43,36,123,98,125,57,57,57,57,54,36,123,98,125,41,41,41,44,36,123,91,46,46,46,39,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,80,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,80,112,112,80,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,39,93,46,106,111,105,110,96,43,96,125,36,123,113,125,96,93,46,109,97,112,40,115,61,62,99,40,52,51,41,46,114,101,112,101,97,116,40,77,97,116,104,46,109,97,120,40,45,120,43,115,46,99,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,65,116,40,41,44,48,41,41,43,99,40,52,53,41,46,114,101,112,101,97,116,40,77,97,116,104,46,109,97,120,40,120,45,40,120,61,115,46,99,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,65,116,40,41,41,44,48,41,41,43,99,40,52,54,41,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,99,40,41,41,46,109,97,116,99,104,40,47,46,123,49,44,50,53,51,125,47,103,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,99,40,49,48,41,43,81,41,41,125,41,40,41]))[::-1]+`99996`))),p+p+p+p+p+p+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+P+p+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pRbZbtsw7FeCvcSalUGyDlvJusdhj@5zMaDpkTaDl3huBwT7@Y6kKMdJ4xZtkdimKIr3obtts1o/3D89feraH9PptGvbb9uvN7erySbbiflds71aNpNm0Z21eZuv8u95nf/Jszavxeesme1Efp7Xk/VqsvvaTG6bh9vJno6pdrNG5PWiOdstutvHv91m0i2m0@V02p5d33eZVWJRR0iLxR@CAkDnETJisSJIFwB@Z9AJ4GcXbbfePJLE9Kv7p2Yt8H28ruXDY5eJL7@26032e9lmG4nvZvn76mY52c233Q1YP7PVMR1TXM8vvVKXeYbb17MQxJd/q3XTZIXIL0NwsMcIrQR65/pbCNE9dGJIjsRCXlgltSqk1zI4fPtCgsVSa4Mr2A0BgQpRHh4L5A6@eMxI6@k0obUGGIhL@FgZSsLiijaQHvgRS6elKxF2QVaaZIeELxgfqgG@lM4yXheKFKuIKETuqI12LKmKknwECWWQC0iyRgbaiv/gpfFkLuxBcElQiVSG2DvAwFFQCdRwxM@BNvD2uDaRvbdsfyHLIjFE/yHHwdLusYkeH3Q4clG9k9CjpiCrMDpgMJpekR3JJnAPehhWSKlIXfK3JqYkK34UfUqF70olLSy5hGkqkoB2KuKFtkap1rDbgIQEuV47jIPaa8CexygAbIrX1RiRj4Kjr22SjLYpygfcZUtJJKVkyf6MKgIIFIb@4KIIkKMpnTA3kQbTqsA04jRUp/dDSrtYD0cE5Z6gz@PDfacTA3VCAzjt1J6mVKMkpmdDfgDVXOAUGlQkuOO551/4pHwYWzDqRAoNUe84gijLNet7U7lqPVet60tAhdhPYoboePgQqbggqHNgJWHsY5o6bgPkqWFNQZ6hI/0HdBkRCzEEqVz8uIPNxVK6HaNTJRyID9RwuB1FVYoitlrluMdVlGKpTI9k0UnMmlMSR7lhNlNFHNY6joCCeY4V@zP136P1iL4aAwSNG/r18w6@H2Cp16I8PkZygCjwqBrGLg42T@Yhq/DC3PLRPE6MOEgiV1oG6s@OOif4MJjRiJQ8zJ5bqNnOtDOw0oR@Wpx6KpU@VfRF@S4Es3mdowm9Pw/Lg@PjjycfLkeCgImzjwL13NgOrR90@ZhzdIqCUJZpgSEbMC2oRtP8MsT@bbG1XAEc5F4p81GleLAxRHPavT3vxtSzCXmyaUW6AUVIqrJ03C1jwRrqApanjosXI1vGW9QrAlL74GsD/Yel@FOIi/l8pn/ibTUEfymEkMNr9OEl@mWoPk0/fXr6Dw)

## [RAD](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/rad)

```javascript
'''rpp>o<def n(x):global l;r=p+p+f+F+P+q+(p+P)*(l-x)+Q+P if x<l else p+p+f+F+P+(p+P)*(x-l)+P;l=x;return r;''a''p=chr(40);P=chr(41);q=chr(91);Q=chr(93);f=chr(123);F=chr(125);l=4;print p+p+p+p+p+p+P+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+P+f+F+P,str().join(map(n,map(lambda x:ord(x)-48,str().join(map(lambda c:`600`+(str(c-99).zfill(2)+`99500`.zfill(10) if c>99 else str(c).zfill(2)+`500`),[40,102,61,95,61,62,123,113,61,40,99,61,83,116,114,105,110,103,46,102,114,111,109,67,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,41,40,51,57,41,59,81,61,99,40,51,52,41,59,98,61,99,40,57,54,41,59,120,61,48,59,99,111,110,115,111,108,101,46,108,111,103,40,81,43,91,46,46,46,96,36,123,81,125,57,57,43,38,59,55,53,42,49,45,108,50,58,56,45,38,111,64,114,112,72,36,123,113,125,36,123,113,43,113,125,114,112,112,62,111,60,100,101,102,32,110,40,120,41,58,103,108,111,98,97,108,32,108,59,114,61,112,43,112,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,113,43,40,112,43,80,41,42,40,108,45,120,41,43,81,43,80,32,105,102,32,120,60,108,32,101,108,115,101,32,112,43,112,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,40,112,43,80,41,42,40,120,45,108,41,43,80,59,108,61,120,59,114,101,116,117,114,110,32,114,59,39,39,97,39,39,112,61,99,104,114,40,52,48,41,59,80,61,99,104,114,40,52,49,41,59,113,61,99,104,114,40,57,49,41,59,81,61,99,104,114,40,57,51,41,59,102,61,99,104,114,40,49,50,51,41,59,70,61,99,104,114,40,49,50,53,41,59,108,61,52,59,112,114,105,110,116,32,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,80,43,112,43,80,43,112,43,80,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,112,43,80,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,44,115,116,114,40,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,109,97,112,40,110,44,109,97,112,40,108,97,109,98,100,97,32,120,58,111,114,100,40,120,41,45,52,56,44,115,116,114,40,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,109,97,112,40,108,97,109,98,100,97,32,99,58,36,123,98,125,54,48,48,36,123,98,125,43,40,115,116,114,40,99,45,57,57,41,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,50,41,43,36,123,98,125,57,57,53,48,48,36,123,98,125,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,49,48,41,32,105,102,32,99,62,57,57,32,101,108,115,101,32,115,116,114,40,99,41,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,50,41,43,36,123,98,125,53,48,48,36,123,98,125,41,44,91,96,43,91,46,46,46,96,40,102,61,36,123,102,125,41,40,41,96,93,46,109,97,112,40,99,61,62,99,46,99,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,65,116,40,41,41,43,96,93,41,41,91,58,58,45,49,93,43,36,123,98,125,57,57,57,57,54,36,123,98,125,41,41,41,44,36,123,91,46,46,46,39,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,80,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,80,112,112,80,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,39,93,46,106,111,105,110,96,43,96,125,36,123,113,125,96,93,46,109,97,112,40,115,61,62,99,40,52,51,41,46,114,101,112,101,97,116,40,77,97,116,104,46,109,97,120,40,45,120,43,115,46,99,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,65,116,40,41,44,48,41,41,43,99,40,52,53,41,46,114,101,112,101,97,116,40,77,97,116,104,46,109,97,120,40,120,45,40,120,61,115,46,99,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,65,116,40,41,41,44,48,41,41,43,99,40,52,54,41,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,99,40,41,41,46,109,97,116,99,104,40,47,46,123,49,44,50,53,51,125,47,103,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,99,40,49,48,41,43,81,41,41,125,41,40,41]))[::-1]+`99996`))),p+p+p+p+p+p+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+P+p+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pRbZTuMw8Ff61njjIjs@ErfAI8/hGa1EKXSXVWhLYKVqf56dGY/T9AgIUJtkPB7Pfbid37@9jcfjdrO5XJ/fPyxHq2wrpr@a9d28GTWz9mKTb/JlfpXX@XOebfJa/MiayVbk13k9elyOtufN6KF5eRjt6JhqO2lEXs@ai@2sfXj9265G7Ww8no/Hm4vF7zazSszqCGkxeyYoAHQdISNmS4J0AeAVg04APzvbtI@rV5KYfnX31KwFvg/XtXx5bTNx9mf9uMqe5ptsJfHdzJ/u7uej7XTd3oP1E1sd0jHFYnrrlbrNM9xeTEIQZ/@Wj02TFSK/DcHBHiO0EuidxWUI0T10ok@OxELeWCW1KqTXMjh8@0KCxVJrgyvYDQGBClEeHgvkDr54zEjr6TShtQYYiEv4WBlKwuKKNpAe@BFLp6UrEXZBVppkh4QvGB@qHr6UzjJeF4oUq4goRO6ojXYsqYqSfAQJZZALSLJGBtqK/@Cl8WQu7EFwSVCJVIbYO8DAUVAJ1HDEz4E28Pa4NpG9t2x/IcsiMUT/Icfe0u6wiR4fdDhyUZ2T0KOmIKswOmAwml6RHckmcA96GFZIqUhd8rcmpiQrfhR9SoXvSiUtLLmEaSqSgHYq4oW2RqnWsNuAhAS5TjuMg9ppwJ7HKABsio/VGJCPgqOvbZKMtinKB9xlS0kkpWTJ/owqAggUhv7gogiQoymdMDeRBtOqwDTiNFSn90NKu1gPBwTljqDL4/19pxMDdUIDOO3UjqZUgySmY0N@ANVc4BTqVSS449jz73xSPgwtGHUihfqoLxxBlOWa9Z2pXLWeq9Z1JaBC7CcxQ3Q8vI9UXBDUObCSMPYxTR23AfJUv6Ygz9CR/hu6DIiFGIJULn7cweZiKd0O0akS9sQHajjcjqIqRRFbrXLc4ypKsVSmB7LoJGbNKYmD3DCbqSL2ax1HQME8h4r9SP2vaD2gr8YAQeOGfn3cwXcDLPValMfHSA4QBR5V/djFwebJPGQV3plbPprHiREHSeRKy0D92VHnBB8GMxiRkofZsYWa7Uw7PStN6KbFqadS6VNFX5RfQjCbjzma0Plzvzw4Pv5w8uFyIAiYOLsoUM@N7dD6XpePOUenKAhlmRYYsh7Tgmo0zS9D7D8XW8sVwEHulDLfVYoHG0M0p93n825IPZuQJ5tWpOtRhKQqS8fdMhasoS5geeq4eDGyZbxFfSAgtQ@@NtC/X4o/hbiZTif6J95WQ/C3QgjZv0bvX6Lfh@rT9OO3t/8)

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish)

```javascript
'rpp>o<def n(x):global l;r=p+p+f+F+P+q+(p+P)*(l-x)+Q+P if x<l else p+p+f+F+P+(p+P)*(x-l)+P;l=x;return r;'a'p=chr(40);P=chr(41);q=chr(91);Q=chr(93);f=chr(123);F=chr(125);l=4;print p+p+p+p+p+p+P+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+P+f+F+P,str().join(map(n,map(lambda x:ord(x)-48,str().join(map(lambda c:`600`+(str(c-99).zfill(2)+`99500`.zfill(10) if c>99 else str(c).zfill(2)+`500`),[40,102,61,95,61,62,123,113,61,40,99,61,83,116,114,105,110,103,46,102,114,111,109,67,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,41,40,51,57,41,59,81,61,99,40,51,52,41,59,98,61,99,40,57,54,41,59,120,61,48,59,99,111,110,115,111,108,101,46,108,111,103,40,81,43,91,46,46,46,96,36,123,81,125,57,57,43,38,59,55,53,42,49,45,108,50,58,56,45,38,111,64,114,112,72,36,123,113,125,36,123,113,43,113,125,114,112,112,62,111,60,100,101,102,32,110,40,120,41,58,103,108,111,98,97,108,32,108,59,114,61,112,43,112,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,113,43,40,112,43,80,41,42,40,108,45,120,41,43,81,43,80,32,105,102,32,120,60,108,32,101,108,115,101,32,112,43,112,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,40,112,43,80,41,42,40,120,45,108,41,43,80,59,108,61,120,59,114,101,116,117,114,110,32,114,59,39,39,97,39,39,112,61,99,104,114,40,52,48,41,59,80,61,99,104,114,40,52,49,41,59,113,61,99,104,114,40,57,49,41,59,81,61,99,104,114,40,57,51,41,59,102,61,99,104,114,40,49,50,51,41,59,70,61,99,104,114,40,49,50,53,41,59,108,61,52,59,112,114,105,110,116,32,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,80,43,112,43,80,43,112,43,80,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,112,43,80,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,44,115,116,114,40,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,109,97,112,40,110,44,109,97,112,40,108,97,109,98,100,97,32,120,58,111,114,100,40,120,41,45,52,56,44,115,116,114,40,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,109,97,112,40,108,97,109,98,100,97,32,99,58,36,123,98,125,54,48,48,36,123,98,125,43,40,115,116,114,40,99,45,57,57,41,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,50,41,43,36,123,98,125,57,57,53,48,48,36,123,98,125,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,49,48,41,32,105,102,32,99,62,57,57,32,101,108,115,101,32,115,116,114,40,99,41,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,50,41,43,36,123,98,125,53,48,48,36,123,98,125,41,44,91,96,43,91,46,46,46,96,40,102,61,36,123,102,125,41,40,41,96,93,46,109,97,112,40,99,61,62,99,46,99,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,65,116,40,41,41,43,96,93,41,41,91,58,58,45,49,93,43,36,123,98,125,57,57,57,57,54,36,123,98,125,41,41,41,44,36,123,91,46,46,46,39,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,80,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,80,112,112,80,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,39,93,46,106,111,105,110,96,43,96,125,36,123,113,125,96,93,46,109,97,112,40,115,61,62,99,40,52,51,41,46,114,101,112,101,97,116,40,77,97,116,104,46,109,97,120,40,45,120,43,115,46,99,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,65,116,40,41,44,48,41,41,43,99,40,52,53,41,46,114,101,112,101,97,116,40,77,97,116,104,46,109,97,120,40,120,45,40,120,61,115,46,99,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,65,116,40,41,41,44,48,41,41,43,99,40,52,54,41,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,99,40,41,41,46,109,97,116,99,104,40,47,46,123,49,44,50,53,51,125,47,103,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,99,40,49,48,41,43,81,41,41,125,41,40,41]))[::-1]+`99996`))),p+p+p+p+p+p+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+P+p+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pRbLTuMw8L5f0RvxxkV2/EjcAkfO4YxWanl06SqUElip2p/vzozHaVoaEKA2yXg8nvfDi@XLw3Z70q7XF09nd/eL0SrbiMnv5ulm3oyaaXu@ztf5Ir/M6/w5z9Z5LX5mzXgj8qu8Hi0Xo81ZM7pvXu5HOzqm2owbkdfT5nwzbe9f/7arUTs9mZ@sz28f2swqMa0jpMX0maAA0FWEjJguCNIFgJcMOgHc7HTdLlevJC/96u6pWQd8H65r@fLaZuL0z9NylT3O19lK4ruZP97czUebyVN7B7aPbXVIxxS3k5lXapZnuH07DkGc/lssmyYrRD4LwcEeI7QS6JvbixCic@hEnxyJhby2SmpVSK9lcPj2hQSLpdYGV7AbAgIVojw8FsgdfPGYkdbTaUJrDTAQl/CxMpSExRVtID3wI5ZOS1ci7IKsNMkOCV8wPlQ9fCmdZbwuFClWEVGI3FEb7VhSFSX5CBLKIBeQZI0MtBX/wUvjyVzYg@CSoBKpDLF3gIGjoBKo4YifA23g7XFtIntv2f5ClkViiP5Djr2l3WETPT7ocOSiOiehR01BVmF0wGA0vSI7kk3gHvQwrJBSkbrkb01MSVb8KPqUCt@VSlpYcgnTVCQB7VTEC22NUq1htwEJCXKddhgHtdOAPY9RANgUH6sxIB8FR1/bJBltU5QPuMuWkkhKyZL9GVUEECgM/cFFESBHUzphbiINplWBacRpqI7vh5R2sR4OCModQZfH@/tOJwbqiAZw2qkdTakGSUzHhvwAqrnAKdSrSHDHW8@/80n5MLRg1JEU6qO@cARRlmvWd6Zy1XquWteVgAqxn8QM0fHwPlJxQVDnwErC2Mc0ddwGyFP9moI8Q0f6b@gyIBZiCFK5@HEHm4uldDtEp0rYEx@o4XA7iqoURWy1ynGPqyjFUpkeyKKTmDXHJA5yw2ymitivdRwBBfMcKvY36n9F6wF9NQYIGjf067cdfDfAUq9FeXyM5ABR4FHVj10cbJ7MQ1bhnbnlo3mcGHGQRK60DNSfHXVO8GEwgxEpeZi9tVCznWmnZ6UJ3bQ49lQqfaroi/JLCGbzMUcTOn/ulwfHxx9OPlwOBAETZxcF6rmxHVrf6/Ix5@gUBaEs0wJD1mNaUI2m@WWI/edia7kCOMidUua7SvFgY4jmtPt83g2pZxPyaNOKdD2KkFRl6bhbxoI11AUsTx0XL0a2jLeoDwSk9sHXBvr3S/GXENeTyVj/wttqCH4mhJD9a/T@Jfp9qD5O/2O7/Q8)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/)

```python
def n(x):global l;r=p+p+f+F+P+q+(p+P)*(l-x)+Q+P if x<l else p+p+f+F+P+(p+P)*(x-l)+P;l=x;return r;
p=chr(40);P=chr(41);q=chr(91);Q=chr(93);f=chr(123);F=chr(125);l=4;print p+p+p+p+p+p+P+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+P+f+F+P,str().join(map(n,map(lambda x:ord(x)-48,str().join(map(lambda c:`600`+(str(c-99).zfill(2)+`99500`.zfill(10) if c>99 else str(c).zfill(2)+`500`),[40,102,61,95,61,62,123,113,61,40,99,61,83,116,114,105,110,103,46,102,114,111,109,67,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,41,40,51,57,41,59,81,61,99,40,51,52,41,59,98,61,99,40,57,54,41,59,120,61,48,59,99,111,110,115,111,108,101,46,108,111,103,40,81,43,91,46,46,46,96,36,123,81,125,57,57,43,38,59,55,53,42,49,45,108,50,58,56,45,38,111,64,114,112,72,36,123,113,125,36,123,113,43,113,125,114,112,112,62,111,60,100,101,102,32,110,40,120,41,58,103,108,111,98,97,108,32,108,59,114,61,112,43,112,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,113,43,40,112,43,80,41,42,40,108,45,120,41,43,81,43,80,32,105,102,32,120,60,108,32,101,108,115,101,32,112,43,112,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,40,112,43,80,41,42,40,120,45,108,41,43,80,59,108,61,120,59,114,101,116,117,114,110,32,114,59,39,39,97,39,39,112,61,99,104,114,40,52,48,41,59,80,61,99,104,114,40,52,49,41,59,113,61,99,104,114,40,57,49,41,59,81,61,99,104,114,40,57,51,41,59,102,61,99,104,114,40,49,50,51,41,59,70,61,99,104,114,40,49,50,53,41,59,108,61,52,59,112,114,105,110,116,32,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,80,43,112,43,80,43,112,43,80,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,112,43,80,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,44,115,116,114,40,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,109,97,112,40,110,44,109,97,112,40,108,97,109,98,100,97,32,120,58,111,114,100,40,120,41,45,52,56,44,115,116,114,40,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,109,97,112,40,108,97,109,98,100,97,32,99,58,36,123,98,125,54,48,48,36,123,98,125,43,40,115,116,114,40,99,45,57,57,41,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,50,41,43,36,123,98,125,57,57,53,48,48,36,123,98,125,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,49,48,41,32,105,102,32,99,62,57,57,32,101,108,115,101,32,115,116,114,40,99,41,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,50,41,43,36,123,98,125,53,48,48,36,123,98,125,41,44,91,96,43,91,46,46,46,96,40,102,61,36,123,102,125,41,40,41,96,93,46,109,97,112,40,99,61,62,99,46,99,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,65,116,40,41,41,43,96,93,41,41,91,58,58,45,49,93,43,36,123,98,125,57,57,57,57,54,36,123,98,125,41,41,41,44,36,123,91,46,46,46,39,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,80,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,80,112,112,80,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,39,93,46,106,111,105,110,96,43,96,125,36,123,113,125,96,93,46,109,97,112,40,115,61,62,99,40,52,51,41,46,114,101,112,101,97,116,40,77,97,116,104,46,109,97,120,40,45,120,43,115,46,99,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,65,116,40,41,44,48,41,41,43,99,40,52,53,41,46,114,101,112,101,97,116,40,77,97,116,104,46,109,97,120,40,120,45,40,120,61,115,46,99,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,65,116,40,41,41,44,48,41,41,43,99,40,52,54,41,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,99,40,41,41,46,109,97,116,99,104,40,47,46,123,49,44,50,53,51,125,47,103,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,99,40,49,48,41,43,81,41,41,125,41,40,41]))[::-1]+`99996`))),p+p+p+p+p+p+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+P+p+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pRbLUtsw8N6vyNGqFUayHrbi0iNnc2aYSYCk0DFJCHQm7c/T3dXKcR6GASaxvVqt9v3Q@u/L/WpZvL7ezRejZbYVk1/t6mbWjtp6c77O1/kiv8ib/CnP1nkjvmfteCvyy7wZPSxG2x/taN4@z0c7OqbajluRN3V7vq0385c/m@VoU39bn9/ebzKrRN1ESIv6iaAA0GWEjKgXBOkCwAsGnQBetl5vHpYvJC39mu5pWAN8H64b@fyyycTZ79XDMnucrbOlxHc7e7y5m422k9XmDiwf2@qQjiluJ1Ov1DTPcPt2HII4@7d4aNusEPk0BAd7jNBKoGduf4YQXUMn@uRILOSVVVKrQnotg8O3LyRYLLU2uILdEBCoEOXhsUDu4IvHjLSeThNaa4CBuISPlaEkLK5oA@mBH7F0WroSYRdkpUl2SPiC8aHq4UvpLON1oUixiohC5I7aaMeSqijJR5BQBrmAJGtkoK34D14aT@bCHgSXBJVIZYi9AwwcBZVADUf8HGgDb49rE9l7y/YXsiwSQ/Qfcuwt7Q6b6PFBhyMX1TkJPWoKsgqjAwaj6RXZkWwC96CHYYWUitQlf2tiSrLiR9GnVPiuVNLCkkuYpiIJaKciXmhrlGoNuw1ISJDrtMM4qJ0G7HmMAsCmeF@NAfkoOPraJslom6J8wF22lERSSpbsz6gigEBh6A8uigA5mtIJcxNpMK0KTCNOQ3V6P6S0i/VwQFDuCLo83t93OjFQJzSA007taEo1SGI6NuQHUM0FTqFeRYI7jj3/xiflw9CCUSdSqI/6xBFEWa5Z35nKVeu5al1XAirEfhIzRMfD@0jFBUGdAysJYx/T1HEbIE/1awryDB3pv6DLgFiIIUjl4scdbC6W0u0QnSphT3yghsPtKKpSFLHVKsc9rqIUS2V6IItOYtackjjIDbOZKmK/1nEEFMxzqNiP1P@M1gP6agwQNG7o18cdfDfAUq9FeXyM5ABR4FHVj10cbJ7MQ1bhjbnlo3mcGHGQRK60DNSfHXVO8GEwgxEpeZgdW6jZzrTTs9KEblqceiqVPlX0RfkpBLN5n6MJnT/3y4Pj4w8nHy4HgoCJs4sC9dzYDq3vdfmYc3SKglCWaYEh6zEtqEbT/DLE/mOxtVwBHOROKfNVpXiwMURz2n0874bUswl5smlFuh5FSKqydNwtY8Ea6gKWp46LFyNbxlvUOwJS@@BrA/37pXgtxNVkMtbXeFsNwU@FELJ/jd6/RL8NNafpX1//Aw)

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7Z1BbtwwDEX3PUWW9qKH6DkML9JuWhTootsgZ58mGTToeCxZDUyKn3pNMUWazMiWqS/yk/z6@vvxx6/vj99@Xi7T25/59Wt@en75@/ff@WGaXl6X68@meZ3fvr@@Tu9f8@5v1X62/YS732sfbTOew4gu93f73c67dz7j/nU6vItFeI4ijFb5tPNHfx85k41X7NJwRd3jRwaM@ghq5L/DPVzcvF8HtwvvjnHN2/mMPbMF1D59du8RHO@kFSvOudab96z4bC1@TQnhz/ZlzEcqeG2mo667NiDsy5iteBOb9sFcP2TR9bPaVpue5@vkjRj5URXsDTpTd@t6xT8bl4sjziXOJc4lzk2HoyWG9/x7qt0Re8PgzHzmPIB9dI6vR6S1G7OEjkNLPEw0X3YZ2C/c@XwBbqOI7INzGpnZMS/@1TgGNbDVpT0jEZZPKO8WWr5FEU@ZdyF2y2ZW4MkzYHrEnXXcPFBllkAzcoGpotVinQOzGTyWTJrH8Ky4IrtAdoHsAnw/fD8eFHw/fD9xC3z/yHy/uQenwKjas@0w2TDZMNmwmDDZ2ABMNkw2TPYYFfkw2nK9VEfPj4qrvtVpkj6H/S5FHNVlf1mbPseI1ZpmTZbRRz/EUAsmfHelq47Fdo0Nb3e@q9OLx9XEHPrM6TNP12feyeto4M3cVLKqd53oCnSikKO5suWkjebpdJTApjPZNHPFUwUrwUrWPzaNTWPT2DQ2jU1j09g0cRpxGlfKlXKlca/Ug8P3qmnPM8rysZ2MWgTrXBTqrFKd9Zr1SpVebVa54yq3rKWe6jsJIwUaCRwBR0Kr48SqBTLzir0UUavnpsmO1j@mSO/dDtEJgOoXvdPoVqFbhW4VulVokNjv6/GUYOiwDjuv9EbTG02XUo@IKHH0QOYmT00bTG1GDZY@VZB5@sypT5HkktMpHoSY11Q1LuRv8QpOy875Zh4dYzPqJ1h/A9dPBIjd0e08yje2@z9c/9jKVDoMym4uEo1l8ipymWPN6hIHnLTrdF1r3hhVMXGfH96FvWX4rZFsHQ/@FRq9a1DiKxfrZAR9YgWfJ5j5LGD/7g1YCK4fFgIWgjwfeQbyfBnzfPR@gylgCrlLogaiBqIGogZyl/l9JC9NDjK@ZHw5@da558uhvp4IiwgL1qaXAiFrj7WnoZKWsTpAUW3FVj9IbV1bajRoq/F4s0bon6B/kt9WOMlcUXHOgSlRPskc3U2YvZGZPWO9haripWnVuHLWQVOloozdeE1L@Ey1Errb@0yR@aVOaw9OCk4KTgpOCk4qIydlHgfE5qBYLawWGFwYXBhcGFwYXBhcGNyWzptqRKPaz1S4z2PUHKvi1Vz1vfsTx7KxbCyb@0xr3Va9IiAaiMZKx7KxbCybvZq9mufOc@e5D/LcmQ/mg/lgPgaZDyklb82MGlULZIS96pwalDZk@1b0T5rurwjoaBWeVS0uKr19NDwbqjGoE5KvE6rbj7AOoCtW980@DIG0x6gA4oK4IO4giKuSCwWbLZ6865l6oCPoqOqPtnuj@KOB/TQwD8wD8zpp/ubizNNiZKecADgJTqbiKvEPBU@LBPfAPXAvdz3FPYqIj9hPGyfvnPruq3rYrFV7qFLBp6mPUs/Lo@5ipPZEbacwUrtoVVNnqRFNj9J5K6Um38sOY54pnF9v/57/ya4aSB9s174tb9um4xqNFDRS6JGlRzZwj6xOdO@jL5srqoxpGbp95J5Psr7rKzArOc5o0utW0Ojs93mCY3Ne8Hq5UVCHu4u3i8LrgaTwetmfgH1HAFwnXCdcJ1znwPuPdN0HVUNhvXYYwoC12GondN@MTMbA09s2PSN@Sd15S5WU1Dna5CGGy0vv2xJ5P@v9dmnTraIDcZgrVe1kqsSDcKnwy9ZXa2RvFe@ctYjdSdvd0s53squr9JWvVQ5tSDbrQP1Lqn6lOIbtrHXq4ySnEKVWqo92nv6pKQX7ks/GeWGqXwzlo2zrO5JeVBFJM5oo4TYH45WXrawPRvnvNePxzIbpChDWnPTIZVPdYF3d4INaI/bjyne2KmaJOLk41bNPEMl28NJG737uqB3n1Wu2FutMOZ0nIBb1XKu9KpLTngrY@Xx21qHaOuTcOmsbct6nEq9IVXXYcSuidaK/Sq3B8LWz/U4N0TjJR8l26isepid39bptB5EWX6@TJ1I5k8ZDe47uk/o1LIaVY8655/DccYboSUvzg86Jvv2UfWzo8P5YKd7aUicgV6lyeHPtD9P1z@vvPj1vXuZ//v/T5XL5/OUP)

## [4](https://github.com/urielieli/py-four)

```python
3.6999960040500600030000099500600615006009550060061500600625006002400000995006001400000995006006150060040500600995006006150060083500600170000099500600150000099500600060000099500600110000099500600040000099500600465006000300000995006001500000995006001200000995006001000000995006006750060005000009950060097500600150000099500600675006001200000995006000100000995006000200000995006004150060040500600515006005750060041500600595006008150060061500600995006004050060051500600525006004150060059500600985006006150060099500600405006005750060054500600415006005950060021000009950060061500600485006005950060099500600120000099500600110000099500600160000099500600120000099500600090000099500600020000099500600465006000900000995006001200000995006000400000995006004050060081500600435006009150060046500600465006004650060096500600365006002400000995006008150060026000009950060057500600575006004350060038500600595006005550060053500600425006004950060045500600090000099500600505006005850060056500600455006003850060012000009950060064500600150000099500600130000099500600725006003650060024000009950060014000009950060026000009950060036500600240000099500600140000099500600435006001400000995006002600000995006001500000995006001300000995006001300000995006006250060012000009950060060500600010000099500600020000099500600030000099500600325006001100000995006004050060021000009950060041500600585006000400000995006000900000995006001200000995006009850060097500600090000099500600325006000900000995006005950060015000009950060061500600130000099500600435006001300000995006004350060003000009950060043500600705006004350060080500600435006001400000995006004350060040500600130000099500600435006008050060041500600425006004050060009000009950060045500600210000099500600415006004350060081500600435006008050060032500600060000099500600030000099500600325006002100000995006006050060009000009950060032500600020000099500600090000099500600160000099500600020000099500600325006001300000995006004350060013000009950060043500600030000099500600435006007050060043500600805006004350060040500600130000099500600435006008050060041500600425006004050060021000009950060045500600090000099500600415006004350060080500600595006000900000995006006150060021000009950060059500600150000099500600020000099500600170000099500600180000099500600150000099500600110000099500600325006001500000995006005950060039500600395006009750060039500600395006001300000995006006150060099500600050000099500600150000099500600405006005250060048500600415006005950060080500600615006009950060005000009950060015000009950060040500600525006004950060041500600595006001400000995006006150060099500600050000099500600150000099500600405006005750060049500600415006005950060081500600615006009950060005000009950060015000009950060040500600575006005150060041500600595006000300000995006006150060099500600050000099500600150000099500600405006004950060050500600515006004150060059500600705006006150060099500600050000099500600150000099500600405006004950060050500600535006004150060059500600090000099500600615006005250060059500600130000099500600150000099500600060000099500600110000099500600170000099500600325006001300000995006004350060013000009950060043500600130000099500600435006001300000995006004350060013000009950060043500600130000099500600435006008050060043500600130000099500600435006008050060043500600130000099500600435006008050060043500600805006004350060003000009950060043500600705006004350060080500600435006000300000995006004350060070500600435006001300000995006004350060080500600435006008050060043500600030000099500600435006007050060043500600805006004350060003000009950060043500600705006004350060080500600445006001600000995006001700000995006001500000995006004050060041500600465006000700000995006001200000995006000600000995006001100000995006004050060010000009950060097500600130000099500600405006001100000995006004450060010000009950060097500600130000099500600405006000900000995006009750060010000009950060098500600010000099500600975006003250060021000009950060058500600120000099500600150000099500600010000099500600405006002100000995006004150060045500600525006005650060044500600160000099500600170000099500600150000099500600405006004150060046500600070000099500600120000099500600060000099500600110000099500600405006001000000995006009750060013000009950060040500600090000099500600975006001000000995006009850060001000009950060097500600325006009950060058500600365006002400000995006009850060026000009950060054500600485006004850060036500600240000099500600985006002600000995006004350060040500600160000099500600170000099500600150000099500600405006009950060045500600575006005750060041500600465006002300000995006000300000995006000600000995006000900000995006000900000995006004050060050500600415006004350060036500600240000099500600985006002600000995006005750060057500600535006004850060048500600365006002400000995006009850060026000009950060046500600230000099500600030000099500600060000099500600090000099500600090000099500600405006004950060048500600415006003250060006000009950060003000009950060032500600995006006250060057500600575006003250060002000009950060009000009950060016000009950060002000009950060032500600160000099500600170000099500600150000099500600405006009950060041500600465006002300000995006000300000995006000600000995006000900000995006000900000995006004050060050500600415006004350060036500600240000099500600985006002600000995006005350060048500600485006003650060024000009950060098500600260000099500600415006004450060091500600965006004350060091500600465006004650060046500600965006004050060003000009950060061500600365006002400000995006000300000995006002600000995006004150060040500600415006009650060093500600465006001000000995006009750060013000009950060040500600995006006150060062500600995006004650060099500600050000099500600975006001500000995006006750060012000009950060001000009950060002000009950060065500600170000099500600405006004150060041500600435006009650060093500600415006004150060091500600585006005850060045500600495006009350060043500600365006002400000995006009850060026000009950060057500600575006005750060057500600545006003650060024000009950060098500600260000099500600415006004150060041500600445006003650060024000009950060091500600465006004650060046500600395006001300000995006001300000995006001300000995006001300000995006001300000995006001300000995006001300000995006008050060013000009950060080500600805006000300000995006007050060013000009950060080500600805006000300000995006007050060013000009950060080500600805006000300000995006007050060013000009950060080500600805006000300000995006007050060080500600130000099500600130000099500600805006001300000995006008050060080500600030000099500600705006001300000995006008050060080500600395006009350060046500600070000099500600120000099500600060000099500600110000099500600965006004350060096500600260000099500600365006002400000995006001400000995006002600000995006009650060093500600465006001000000995006009750060013000009950060040500600160000099500600615006006250060099500600405006005250060051500600415006004650060015000009950060002000009950060013000009950060002000009950060097500600170000099500600405006007750060097500600170000099500600050000099500600465006001000000995006009750060021000009950060040500600455006002100000995006004350060016000009950060046500600995006000500000995006009750060015000009950060067500600120000099500600010000099500600020000099500600655006001700000995006004050060041500600445006004850060041500600415006004350060099500600405006005250060053500600415006004650060015000009950060002000009950060013000009950060002000009950060097500600170000099500600405006007750060097500600170000099500600050000099500600465006001000000995006009750060021000009950060040500600210000099500600455006004050060021000009950060061500600160000099500600465006009950060005000009950060097500600150000099500600675006001200000995006000100000995006000200000995006006550060017000009950060040500600415006004150060044500600485006004150060041500600435006009950060040500600525006005450060041500600415006004650060007000009950060012000009950060006000009950060011000009950060040500600995006004050060041500600415006004650060010000009950060097500600170000099500600995006000500000995006004050060047500600465006002400000995006004950060044500600505006005350060051500600260000099500600475006000400000995006004150060046500600070000099500600120000099500600060000099500600110000099500600405006009950060040500600495006004850060041500600435006008150060041500600415006002600000995006004150060040500600415004
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3VkJjiMxCPzRCt/t/z8sOztp0FIN7suJMhMpsnwAdnEY0/nxSH9q//pVokyF6KulRP9@vT@7NTzbXnS/xmcbs1oesknNzHF8SStZ01yK6n7//5sNelaLzNU8B7AMUXdJb7utPDRRbyYvXg08CbapZzMgU9Z@aXq@rOuXAProDn206fuyQ7/KLdmmj8FW7AJiHHw1dagjZVAfAlfNVcgDjII0inm1ux40U2z72qZqWjuzi/o8gmXT0hKAVVafKut8Zt3xrot51MIqY3ZVL2cxAEnNtidoP2lxeGLwbzj4MSKGY8xrvE3ocjTCI9MRV4RIkaJps2xC4AjiJ4tpeGMrZafkwAKreSeofxshdkmARtC2h8kebqT7Cw11x8MMkiNMuAQweDIPygbtQC5cgy1F4KtH1I0BjsYqGYYsiG@wWAzsHYq6qRGE3o5I2dFAseFhSwXmjl0DepgqLMOoEWzkiyk4QctuiePBSZG6mTWAMLlwo75BNxc@TeHebe5OnnZSSBsL8XKWc9w5s0HuNEMLGe9UR1ijqVKScyTbT1iZxbkLz2TL4D7XYtErhzc3zdRl2L8YVQ@SfeSmhCzbyXg7ZNGQOFMbZuNDk5QriuzXVrJXA5N8hQk4nKwmM02DNFKuBzuDKHYajt56Ksvk@1ciQv0VupyqBsTfeZQwN3y7ZbiWL3HZZF9X9IJJ1@ZZCXqLaZTnYhbcR125g8lO8E5iChuX6@8exq87tiQ0kJude1Hg4xRhmPqWuGVgP8aQ5hhO0EGTi0Bc7DlbHNqpnDqbg9XeHgE3ltmT3su5eItbrGCxcsL@8jpoLabFbu4mLNwhDrCuQ1mGW46l7OFCPyewNbuYetE@g22vHrcdc02HKmkTuwsNhxfbbdqPoXLO904UUrfDwZ0UbhMG641aLxDNCV9w2blRDGoh@LYX4eN6UxrNyk7t8NXacBnE1R00op1qe1XSZIL1gaE928nWJuR7ak2/Uq1O5dWZluL/x2t7ltazQzfxEbt7hp3opbfgWQczb5CEwxcWqHNgKbHYnyKZK34PfQdaziNq89kG2iOZcH48/gI)

Answer (score 6):

## 3. JavaScript → Python 2 → Foo

### JavaScript

Classic JS quine. This is a full program which outputs to console:

```
(f=_=>console.log(`print(${String.fromCharCode(39)}${String.fromCharCode(34)}(f=${f})()${String.fromCharCode(34)}${String.fromCharCode(39)})`))()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f9fI8023tYuOT@vOD8nVS8nP10joaAoM69EQ6U6uATISNdLK8rPdc5ILHIGqtcwttSsxSFjolkLNEylOq1WU0MTtxrc5momaAJ1/v8PAA)

### Python 2

Python code basically prints out the JS code with quotes:

```
print('"(f=_=>console.log(`print(${String.fromCharCode(39)}${String.fromCharCode(34)}(f=${f})()${String.fromCharCode(34)}${String.fromCharCode(39)})`))()"')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EQ11JI8023tYuOT@vOD8nVS8nP10jASKlUh1cAmSk66UV5ec6ZyQWOeenpGoYW2rW4pAx0awFGqZSnVarqaGJWw1uczUTNIE6ldQ1//8HAA)

### Foo

Foo code is JS code with quotes:

```
"(f=_=>console.log(`print(${String.fromCharCode(39)}${String.fromCharCode(34)}(f=${f})()${String.fromCharCode(34)}${String.fromCharCode(39)})`))()"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vP//9fSSPNNt7WLjk/rzg/J1UvJz9dI6GgKDOvREOlOrgEyEjXSyvKz3XOSCxyzk9J1TC21KzFIWOiWQs0TKU6rVZTQxO3GtzmaiZoAnUq/f8PAA)

Comment: Why not e.g. `String.fromCharCode(39,34)` to save on the repeated invocations?

Comment: @ETHproductions I.. actually had no idea you could do that >_<

Comment: Or at least `String.fromCharCode(39)+String.fromCharCode(34)` to save a little bit ;-)

Answer (score 5):

## 1. Foo

### Foo

A simple [Foo quine:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/160963/31957)

```
>&41>&60>&99>&36>&40>&60>&41>&62>&105>&36>&34>&38>&62>&34>&40>&62>&41>&60>&40(<)>(">&"$i>)<($c<)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vP///fTs3E0E7NzMBOzdLSTs3YDMg3gPDB4kZ2aoYGphAJYxMgtoAIgthghUYIA0wMNGw07TSU7NSUVDLtNG00VJJtNP//BwA)

Answer (score 5):

## 2. Python 2 → Foo

i used the basic python quine, then added the quotes

python:

```
_='_=%r;print chr(34)+_%%_+chr(34)';print chr(34)+_%_+chr(34)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P95WPd5Wtci6oCgzr0QhOaNIw9hEUzteVTVeG8pRx5CDS/3/DwA)

foo:

```
"_='_=%r;print chr(34)+_%%_+chr(34)';print chr(34)+_%_+chr(34)"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vP//9fKd5WPd5Wtci6oCgzr0QhOaNIw9hEUzteVTVeG8pRx5CDSyn9/w8A)

Answer (score 5):

## 5. ><> → JavaScript → brainfuck → Python 2 → Foo

Obligatory brainfuck answer.

### ><>

```
'rpp>o<(f=_=>{q=(c=String.fromCharCode)(39);Q=c(34);s=c(92);console.log([...`print(${q+Q+s+q}rpp>o<(f=${f})()${Q+q})`].map(s=>c(43).repeat(s.charCodeAt())+c(46)).join())})()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3NCoMwEIRfRugugT1UKYiNUHwC6bGUKmniD2piklvw2dMUSk/DzPDNqMmNMZ6sMbW@guIvXoedg@B3b6dtIGX12oy9bfRbIuQlVi0XkBdYuaTlGSuhN6cXSYse4EFEnUmghyzsrGWO7cd/OwvqQMAstCnF7klrb8DxWkCRI1lpZO/Bkfjd3TwgslReEGnW05bsl4/xAw)

### JavaScript

```javascript
(f=_=>{q=(c=String.fromCharCode)(39);Q=c(34);s=c(92);console.log([...`print(${q+Q+s+q}rpp>o<(f=${f})()${Q+q})`].map(s=>c(43).repeat(s.charCodeAt())+c(46)).join())})()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU3dCoIwFH4ZL85hdC5SArEJ4RNIlxE51ixFt7mNbobPvhZ09fH9z@IjvHSTDQdtniolGPmDt3HjIPk1uEm/aHRm7d7CdTmAUNbY9FxCWWHjM9ZHbKTR3iyKFvOCGxENNhcDFHFjPfNs2521rTnn7SKOOwIWsc8qDndahQXPWwlVieSUVSKAJ/m/uwRAZNk8IdJsJp3pr5/SFw)

### brainfuck

```javascript
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VtbCsMwDPvfVTJ6p21QGIN9DHb@7AoNnWRZdr8D8kN@xen9c3u@9@/jNecgf9t1DGNMtnoR5lxBPXzyyEGssn8VNb@f8yHSJT4HCAiiWAfAxQyWLybXxoHTzE3RTZHc6tW7WzAlvFWgJGWjQq2PgePJTEBKyzJTqpLUWoABNxwnFIYowfGJ@kwg6/jEPm9WQDWxYoZ7I5YyvtQB9XoHXyNID6pQkdDu16NXhS1B3yXJx2tflAvPaPr9TL5VR2dRT8TeKGe4JyhRbvJkKAgLazKhyyaflKK20L7L8FwA6tVTfnEN1hntAvRCSDxsmZi2A4fp4we7/Ge2D@s3NzaDu19CM0pYqGpft3/SsD@Zpc4rfd01mQbP4swdZinE33TbZc4f)

### Python 2

```python
print('"\'rpp>o<(f=_=>{q=(c=String.fromCharCode)(39);Q=c(34);s=c(92);console.log([...`print(${q+Q+s+q}rpp>o<(f=${f})()${Q+q})`].map(s=>c(43).repeat(s.charCodeAt())+c(46)).join())})()"')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3NCoMwEITfRQR3CexBpSA2QvEJpMe2VEn9K5rEJJciPrtNaelpmPmYGf1yg5LxvmszSgdRcI2M1oU6QsfvvFgXDoKfnYc9dUbN5dCYUj1ahCTDvOICkhRz6zWLMRdKWjW1NKkeLkRUf1fDdWEVs2zZ/tvh2m0IGK6VT7G@0dxosLwQkCZIptVt48CS@N2dHCAyDw@I9FSj9PbTDyLc9zc)

### Foo

```python
"'rpp>o<(f=_=>{q=(c=String.fromCharCode)(39);Q=c(34);s=c(92);console.log([...`print(${q+Q+s+q}rpp>o<(f=${f})()${Q+q})`].map(s=>c(43).repeat(s.charCodeAt())+c(46)).join())})()"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3BCoMwEETv/QwRuouwhyoFsRGKXyA9ltJKGq1F3ZjkFvz2NIXS0zAzvJmeOYRkb7Su@QS9uIvarwKkuDgzLgP1hufm1ZmGnwohL7FqhYS8wMpGLQ9YSV4sT4omHuBKRA8dQQepX7M2s9m6/bdT328ImPo2pvi40dxpsKKWUORIRmnVObAkf3dnB4hZLI@I9OZxifbLJ7sQPg)

Answer (score 5):

## 9. JavaScript → Foo → Brainfuck → Wumpus → RAD → ><> → Python 2 → Brain-Flak → 4

This... was.. fun.
No idea why I decided that 4 should be added, no idea why I remade the entire thing (of course, copy-pasting stuff around), but I did it :D

### JavaScript

```
(f=_=>{q=(c=String.fromCharCode)(39);Q=c(34);b=c(96);console.log(Q+[...`${Q}76+&;l2:6-&o@${q}${q+q}rpp>o<def n(x):global l;r=p+p+f+F+P+q+(p+P)*(l-x)+Q+P if x<l else p+p+f+F+P+(p+P)*(x-l)+P;l=x;return r;''a''p=chr(40);P=chr(41);q=chr(91);Q=chr(93);f=chr(123);F=chr(125);l=4;print p+p+p+p+p+p+P+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+P+f+F+P,map(n,map(lambda x:ord(x)-48,str().join(map(lambda c:${b}600${b}+(str(c-99).zfill(2)+${b}99500${b}.zfill(10) if c>99 else str(c).zfill(2)+${b}500${b}),[`+[...`(f=${f})()`].map(c=>c.charCodeAt())+`]))[::-1]+${b}99996${b})),${[...'pppppppPpPPfFpPPfFpPPfFpPPfFPppPpPPfFpPP'].join`+`}${q}`].map(s=>c(43).repeat(s.charCodeAt())+c(46)).join().match(/.{1,253}/g).join(c(10)+Q))})()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVLBjpswEP0VDmjx1MEbQkJrvEStVsrZUY9RtBAHElYOOIZWqIhvT21Cu6uAPH543sx43vCe/c4aoUvV@lV9zG83VCRvybq/JkgkP1tdVidS6Pryes70qyEACimwbSJQuAR2MDuNgIm6amqZE1mf0BbvCCGp22@HrxF@YnIRR/5T/d3tr4NZ@Dpopdb1yzEvnAp1EJ9kfcikI5lOFFa4wBvM8RUjhTl8QdLvAG8xd8rC6V6kk8smdz54E6vzJWDOZNIxnbe/dOVo5nmZ56lEnDVazoHxOwqAXUdEg7EPi0JgxYiChYGbCa7A5FsyZTRox4r/Xv5/8ekW1j5@89klU6garcwuh2PmdHGtj6Zlf/lt1rQaAXmvywp9YojY7Q9DNJ/bDSNLEj6lQP4UpZRoAdg6KF3dGdNxMAcrj1hTetdnjHsImkJgtkvvEzKTdvtiAATpntg7iGQtiJgG/aNFADjdA@zi2A/2U2FKozELzNzeZvHU/eGK82LzYPinc28/Npvi1P4Fw1SyMSXRMgSic5VnLWoe6htnBJNMYCJacUbPpA9mi1U4PJ8mj7AK4C2AbeZ2@ws)

Since the output is too big for TIO to return, [Here's](https://tio.run/##XVJbb9owFH7vr7AqVOyZmGvZQhq0rhOa9rKwPuyhQiMxCclmYuMkGwzx25ntuA0Asv2dc75zTxQW6emU81UMSJaLqiRlxsEUfH3@VpU3qwo4qcVdLspuwrk@tUrRZpw3PCsYYiTDLE8q@rtB1g4eQHcV/@nmFWMqwpu5iXOhklW0Bybk32ojqsI@REYXPBXphzE0YRrZuMtw1f3@@BkkVWNRXkrVuFhB7MuU58M6bZIVqbmI2FuCblwpzjq3Uu34KipaYBQNsZGbKaWhmtInjb4o1FCA86giGEPCwrP5XKguah2p5VRSF3rOMXuq5PmiaimmKQe3sywPGZBxUbFycntDw/KVcDrBxP/pTw9bH1L/uZRZviaJ5JunNJRP6ptBcOgib@5TOBwhL1KvO0Ye5XnBWUwYX8M5fiGELFuH@fH9GN95bDAZO3f8Y@uwPaqDt0cpxJQ/rOIE5HCHJmvGI1UO86QvsMAJnuEAbzEUOEDvIHN2CM9xALIE7B4YiFkRg4ZnWTuHIRx4zN95Mi4rmQPptdthuy18mko46iEvqFEfeVuD3L7pQ6Mh8hKD@gMFZxbeIxVv5Ak1g9JkfP0HbyewVej7Wg46m1DA3Nws3ESrEOwmXK5Uy87oQ6coJUTkF89yeMagk9YhOo57Pf1gqEnUcV1E/iUZY3CAsDa47n3NsOp@D@nx0Knr1vMxfldO1gV1Xpb1htSmW4fkiCBaLoiugfpTSqhd9GMJEcLLBUIvk4nTX9jErjs2UVCnddBR2qL@BSIIktnVFZzp2wvT7BIv9VdwtCkLlRKOhojIWMRhCYur/Mo4RnZMSHmUNIVdcuh3BvfDY3dtLVRPAM8R0s38Bw) a tester that cycles trough all the languages.

### Foo

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7V07diQ3DMx1DKXtt8dy6vtH8v5sSauZ6SZQKFSBo3ioJkgQfxT@/ueft7fX4/Tv219H7C@6cGnd1R/f/N3LazUtvJMLrPlAPuWukreF/vt8@/lPXv4PjT8MMb/GowB/8TL52W/ST@nSBx@Qz9kw6VjufCbP/AGC2Jxw/3tfyee/5cCXM5v8uLbg9p2MhTT5DALrvgEwe5wlxMfbT32vQ2Qkv/l9efHbJ7kzSLNHa4O1mzq7/eazqP482ea//mMOWyU8vta7Xvn4g99@uX1pQwW@uQXmr7JJCw788r/8RX4HHxPZbMXlmebuPfzyEvnzzOKL5OuHeQHk90ZeOuiPenziAc6rP5a1@jgfDZNvbet@Jn87W/fL7VsEOPEbPWd@H1s36fBaKXfMZmOib0xUEB7r6xEi0a9axPnrvnmVfE1PLv0I0S4P4RCQe@nT@x6Sn3cuHa/n5bXaHl9fRUp0lyS5JHj68kfqc3zSGuE7@SyeZjI1zewx5fp65te2g379Mkj@DNZHGr2CrF349h1YO0h@iDRJ5k7d/lCODzP/DI4P2vwDX8fj2x/P/YuSfxr3B23@4DHI8T/I6G15JYAT4ha1yr0dfm2P1PcKjV6HCghyRbdaBUmuqtO@xAV/@1bn1xDnVzqfvMNrfT6E/L7y@TBifcINLwjRZ8wLKoHupnpHeiObFq88FZ8Ts@LJ36lr8UzxWdVlAr4vF@jmegGrnVza4Yzl3WUVnzk/3CNflR/AX7tNPpnF@wAwmsMdVZ/gtTJhD6Chl8e7KDv1lTbkluBZgDt/8pK/3XLLbPGZ5OKwIZV0dob3EIEjqHJ5ZL0CSqBbOZuV2VuE@Qe5vf@T7w08F/2Ke34/aWCX630S@HFwhVgzC1vBLJPv1aObI19M2@ORDu6TnyDIx3QWLWql6v2pmEznX8sD1Bvh2CH1Pkc2FJsCWaRWCh0UlOZt5N2HT7GCXaLSNdbO0NyTT4326PB@RXVHwWf4SiF6fEVv38WQSpHvD26Zu31777cEpVnN@12HKe7Ld1JVDS/HJykNYeTXPo0qtzLWwe3q4KmTzy4OKEBvqL41pI8CnsjGuT3cAdwlXz2Ygzm6kgQ38VaTO7tEviK8B@YNlJHvIQbqYn2CCuDr0oDV5ybdH/2ah9jWqd4fmT2c@6FQs7wkhtOrFhxOuDyi98K5EU51B0NahlYFEtyynE@Q/JyXQrsSOfK5vFVf1Mr0f5YXBnt5WGqs@qQRvTzG9k9yFqc0Z8eKWyTtoKIP/Em@U5wSsCL89hVh7dc/kGhnoEiJ4vNKNLHqaoqo5Fe90LL9IeP8hlEwOHyB0t2eryoIdGsKudu/FklzdKnRKswu8Tfw31LScArVaH8i0G0n5y5Jfm3dT/D4dKMT2nrfRN6tKj5p7za1pA6@wCITVNPOoFrdE5rINiy2H3j7M9Jgq8zPHRnScMbQAfR@auIa808pflgVfdOKugh1fUSBkd7YdatPNPiXk7Ol5CtrgVS4o8lDga/LgVbZlwTmwSvapHZBuIPk3si4RMgObuEw2b1VncEu3qlFWpkMLjW9v7JojzjQ7@9lS3pfnA9I7QyDguC0en7N55Cx@gZUQNCLW7Ts5E/kz21XLCNfMqIXH06xF//ni1qtmQZBvnEssMXh1TljKlbnUOb3TfvzJb@U6nsn3wdxQsjsUS3vIwS6ORD65Q5vU2lBu4CIZXlEzeLQtspHkWomuyMwxda@3e0VSsA1DaFU/6rOlHDBz@RiU5K6lhKkVn076mDCFnU0TBBsfv/UVz7cYS0O08MpvDsf7rz9Ofg0j9c9En0bRD6AxS2O8W4c81uGu1G3L4vKtSz5tcv7sOcMAq45TEsiWyV//6H1gVdInDEQod2x86PX6ms/X9QsTmahNnBnWHx@VWG5avPPn8sAt/mldeV6D69FoP759iusPq2Wm7JTA8MWuem/EtQmn@AnuoHdLFQAnsDuxitQye9X6AODLfLM@LjN5AKfMkbv23JLI/MrVAPDPD5NY@9sEeL2jQt7AQlu53aOZEW3qaMHvH3T9BaO@S3TW7fI3yi91Sr5VQ4NZfaYqsqm0iaV99Jk9alUSUP0vq@1kC9vsE4HfCS/P@lCP2OIzf98@6aWD6i4xbWyF1jcov94VKFK21QB@PY1WPr6kgqYYmGmGcP8mNdfgtFNpCZ5NVVTmUyeSxH5Ll3eeIhyK1apmc0hzgTvSwvBKh1OLwdSbXHD9R6fkZ137e2rRq@esziRx1A1mcXETjaezSGs95WncqyDV4zFblkHrxhV4xzC7pBHJFm3@mwCNNBV0hjd9ZeSS3LJJgNWkVvYukd2DPETuWVW/3awg1sfmEp0EK2Pl2Tr8WHupWQYpXTkbBms0sGXC25rlXyDIeuEwTQSgTrABxAlzcbOEgC@wNlZ6hhPIGRZ21V2YfcFTHM4uko4zC6igUzp4T0mBfXuLC0LdHs4SpvV9hwxhHbtrE18e9XTGcT152XyZ@a5CFkeqbbNP35NAajX1YgOM7kK390H8ndMc2X9fXONiHF4bTWiVQc3fltgsEo3yXmm@IZHQD3x@iY6vB0nXTSSzCXJWdfOYBEth5Pv1MaGlvzK4nIVpVla8IOupTnS233EFeUNRsICSr4f8kN7lqf3iLtvv/mIsQjtdqICC1L9xOf3Cpi1@/u9jx85lOrwgy@SmM7Qd2gKRu9zNoduF6cxDuv5Co2C9jY1s1sP7ypolXJ2nkD@bAlYW9win/JSuv2GE14obhmU/F9tZpka86xhfht5WUq@/qHVdnLJH1oxZJm6xbh4@3PqOQnk60vAl9eNZjGwRZ@8uKyu5xe3GJUL2gmHFitoHwNi9/Jq0JJe9@gAJc3O0XAAVKlzHiwOWsWszS/b2Tv5zEkUMlIDV9xiKTWA9fyOUiMNWeatCAuqOp2EyIrVJ8wW0SOvdHkUzbycv6/s9sbw@QchdK6v/MH8shq7nmEizD9oRpMmSLVkpFdnhCbseOvIt5jsSYjzKyuK7@Rv6OY3SH5Juyce6hwRDfj99ucOHxGw@riQHZJGr@Yb@8n8Uyz48gT3LMEnm99nnW79OEKi6be@9BP5GwT2b5K/T2Afo/i0Wfr6QsQwSuPsYMUE9sMHu0oAvqCUu09@XVfQboHXvOrwSkftgza/qkNSz3bs4hYxXgDl91XjX2fLWotb@hmhrotTeTa5ZicXv/Kd0c4grCNkoz0cXojG@YfUvu4d66OlOUThTgcxf2QpH59fyka8pfikR0lidweGKzzMMoZ4lGZhA1ESqbUzkgSbwqzs9kbInx/mVXn7fXZEBWaX0WQPCcXXFxopmMfnFBopAaj3kZ2M8gZhWzhQ2jRpKH1uJJl9MPwP5rcM1icWAfP7jsFwPEa3lbVcNYdXXS4QJrH2ufGXf10HWGfR6Vk0k8vF7y3D6hQvkFOdwsyVlwHUpklVD7wsj2S5A8flkY2aljO/rA6MjiB3qNZcBa0ijpBVCi8AYIucwx/QuTx@IrRpBneDgXeZfOlhqoRuDsrdSFhB@du35hUfrM6Si/l6@3Mmbgff/iSz7uTX@Dm8VsgG3eQ321jo0iYzYxFe2@NlMPaPI2y1fytGkB8@CIiuo0h3HkCP03wSOL19x1w7lErVgYqOJVIOhEV2Vo3VKS5FucA1cp3y8QZ2bdVwcSmsnl9ZRbBKm@z8Y6THxw18kOr5BQUWTvrUmz3SL0J2JBmH4YjVHYrSpCvSKxIS@Ez@nFGrwRbmzexeQD2/82j6LPOb28Yu8AUEj@8Y3rL5iPyGTKWADdDby9N@dmCoUjccZ7UJ7KKR3qHoPrEpzEp2a2pjUcyuIdC1Ph5fyd7w6A2qIjKa45sMVK3WxUmWqhHJP0T5/1hSPI@PYTcSkFqn1HgfwRbmSRZv5O1v38Q6MQ5Ue/vyJgNpOoPqAcanM4x4C/FhlMLKbXUolfAGa7cHxu3RhjYgVXRrq4pgqHNi9vM6@SOr/oKhzilVfzH4gjGIhfkEt/XpIfr3jU9PBKW5K@4Nj/R6@YfV7Qzihd6iU5hZ5p/g7R/EDAGvl0fy0QT9/SmF/vEpzCNq/J3GEhXsDTSLU/h9x0Cq9xhG3wVcI1Ib0wNbJMNbMyu6Y5J/j/f@lXxW2F3ujFMV3Szbr@6Ms1Cl5vf//vaFr1/y9ifoyITkn/D6U8zv3/WofvssxTdAiwV@rd/IVrql8EwuQS2WuP0pnl5Q72/6@jOKb4Cd@Lz9Y9brZ4m@CdzCKmoVPeMcYpv9/WeiPQN0hfjts0Tfnh4PGbaIWvZ0sObwskjD55Ob4Qp58Bi310EB6hWXhIZSyQ7QA3@giXwVlCAYUK28BLy5tKqdwQS2t6yD@7CoACzu31e3i5eqOufxf20rk/orSALW2ddAhtMcZJv1oECVpndpFgHoxOcXsC5BsziVW56DYJWyoHTAnYGHUrm9nqJGtsNkOncRcotLx1ely2OgB81Bq7IfqXn7Nvm/Askvi9V2ZKI9EwHb9oMpJsEVejjEZczvYTr@JJ/ltjugNM@RcBdWJSu63YMjPf6@jEVIH0ukZUbFC9ukFWJoLs@sqYOrzL/J/M0Hb19@emS53p8e3rvg8U0O7604vNMHlIGnMrklPXvJb9e2yLJGQ4MZWtbo5zCiyDcNhuHy@5aVHl3ki5hXdSlOCzEgNpuDzRUBkOpJgdEIWqM0CP/mA@hjrUzjqhoPVqBbOOURMXt00dYpWJ1T4vxX1kCsPmnhHoIqJSl32TbGPfB6QeS7mgKNXZwKXmVjuEOS/KGj1oP@/vCQFzrQ7eEOULo4DSKGUiXN/FNbi/aMG9mpNoGdnFzZ9PZVS5oz2ibw72EpztJtZ/55yuxZ/bL8fZ@RX7ybQyoDUvv2iY5w7As1SS6aP8Mxehs3WLu98CBa1gZrt5cDr3C44Pjtj7jghz@OM/@I84EUtMuez2KOj3VBLaey2MO7gzDM1PMPeCsFZk8ls6I/mpL8/rwyUPEtDqZxYlb09uAV3V5vRUDxdcpVQrhD@a08In@@x2Ot@ABfzDexWhsGxR6fuhHJVHyCp5JweBvfyre3t38B)

### brainfuck

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7d1Rjhw3DATQA3XgOyUBAhgB/GEg598cwTs7bnWx@PZ7tKIoslikJPZfP//8/uOf//7@9@Pj@uXftz@ur/19deBL4z774y@v4u3BR2Z7R8Ij@3Rop57Z3U//hwd/GKWw/hmHWfEZcQ8p5ZTufz3PaSv4/HxP4MbLMz8R1QrJQfyEB@ZI26VBVjOQYoTzBeI9J9TDmgi3k7vkW2fxN7GcVI3fVAuYwz5vWFG8BR/cxb0p3awMP06P5dlZlCbRWqx7FevGartZ7RiGO4fVlp/DzieKxQeKz@zIQ3aw4WA4M1s7435JNwQarjVMQPtzWsn2m69J9/qoQ0fVaTSLNVda82BzZu/r7X2h0TNqRr0Fy9l6ta0fe9MwzS/YPbv/PUroZPeP@Mew7Ke81Jv7iOLsrO4vEI94xKMd2jF9gVA2wkawE2ZqI2zEfQnqYbyqe8v92ozZxQq20GsLfcouaT2RsjczL6RXNjxJt8LG7kCnj4KiI/OT21xzyPvqQk4uvBk2dVXDr/Fr/Hojv86m0odaCR8acesM4WQcNZzh4KfvnVeR5KfmruXKqbPdfA037GQsHhOWh34oB@VCUO7hN/E6SKYuNzWGaBs5bNLQc0n5bT4wIVVIldRxQuq4LokLOtwPbIYVmIsc3rnbl59eqKlTXKStJbbVOLaSzIUkW3Eg6B8fWojouz26ai0lJKtmT1r2IzO6SCyA0ODwe7SGkZvldCk7n/ECGope55od@BJKwxbXHlLT@lzQalRadK3GiUX4voK2@ck1VHvIQ6EbdKsjSMH5MJTr9NS1tYSOYsLuY7auWr1aVRadYy5cGKfeBxTJvHA1upLtmTzkgIBNV/iyUacke4t@jtAn2@ZgHV6k7qou1Sk73AZgThkjUhjoME2M2OPBnfyZ5bN8GoYtczelZiXWQcOjFewRS8oivNeFI0P5YgnHck20hMq1JApKnN5ZvD@UYa9kF05llUGacpGm940UjM7R76osLvkCIydu2HuvMkRHWDS4EtFjYdLhM9IpvG/0eY8WRbyCyLK5ZbqD9Y0xCJViwoNDrwPsxeGH6y7M4yl4pYLpd3HVQ3H4arF@2M1TslTmGEVpJcd95cybfX45euuLdNQM9raVY8y@crxzP7rWwlFG@5aSfCYzyP5AC@nOTkR/OJ3cRJYqol4@rBf9VQb9UsKZR88dSNFGtBFtlkcb4WZ3KiQ6iU6i097oJEQJUcczIkFH0BF0BJ1I6USbzagkMrEBkakhMqUz5554LmIm52cOrMRAMVAMFAPvHSYK7sZLkTM233bOK5oHAob3MlmW5e1PAdhrx0XBFEzBFEzBFHw@OdWAjk2ySTZJwWySyka5MS9mkZyYE3NiGsMOoSSVcWNeLLBwYk7MiWlspcq6Lihq0Lk8g3HnDFpAC2ix0JoZM/BoVDi7vnquVfd9CagkQntAsw70fFoyK73a/MXL5Lwi@bnV@uYH3uftDMKAf61JLvcuD8QnL15pM5Z/vjVUoZ41M2bgsVjh7Dq5iDHBiaIxtSntyL5eV3YaU1d09YlRUAWqQNUAj5POTt95xy/MvizP6eODpLuc/KXyE@8Uk5ZxqeYvXsxVdANYTFH4UPhQ@MDJ26RT3lbehvJQXpouTZemy2yl6fN5CdoUWkwAsqLeYLFG4FLjx0vXS7cXOJG5wJyPda1zXZfGXBpryCpLU0tlS4xKRo0crlnM5XbR2pji3LlDyY3pdN/tIocpbshAKkiFrQQXW5K1lg1TjaizuhpENp5aV1WJvTmA4TbEmrWFZyy4AoSR3wcEdOZ4RW6PNrLZPMvFiDaGermyLCUuD0RiUNf1PIrWiT0GX6IN3hVm9QFiqacsraco3mXKFv5VosorXfoe9OGbM0zkoE3ZnsyTjnRgHsyDeTnjAPoOm5Zjk2vRZCsrFrRc2bEO67AO65iyji@PpOHxGm7a@@Ct51t8i2/xLb7Ft/gW3@JbfMvOqxlALxqGEuID32LB8ZK5aPyGdBpTeAaatiMdG@IV2eX9XSw7mRCg3dhLWzzLbwNo7FTbtNM1AW3TlkYP3dV0V7vWfyYrVzDPnfYyex24djGRon5omCv2WsNeNZEdkJbDNU1kuxStiewy0qSJrCayxLpvFD6W7ABVZTveKY/Ly5FQ47gdcbEObQN1g8mUUgV6/YB9Q1y4m5VcTTCB5X1aq1L/vVd2NIHuCubylM15ipJM2I4oyQxnE5UUEa/u@@7b@pNS51dyESpeFC7eiDC/@d/f89OjMffk2NF7fbssQ7jq00OjduE2ALh/leGuQDziEW@CeLRj@gFCMVPTM1N2wkyZKTNlpqgx8WjH9CCOmT4//bePj/8B)

### Wumpus

```
"76+&;l2:6-&o@'''rpp>o<def n(x):global l;r=p+p+f+F+P+q+(p+P)*(l-x)+Q+P if x<l else p+p+f+F+P+(p+P)*(x-l)+P;l=x;return r;''a''p=chr(40);P=chr(41);q=chr(91);Q=chr(93);f=chr(123);F=chr(125);l=4;print p+p+p+p+p+p+P+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+P+f+F+P,map(n,map(lambda x:ord(x)-48,str().join(map(lambda c:`600`+(str(c-99).zfill(2)+`99500`.zfill(10) if c>99 else str(c).zfill(2)+`500`),[40,102,61,95,61,62,123,113,61,40,99,61,83,116,114,105,110,103,46,102,114,111,109,67,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,41,40,51,57,41,59,81,61,99,40,51,52,41,59,98,61,99,40,57,54,41,59,99,111,110,115,111,108,101,46,108,111,103,40,81,43,91,46,46,46,96,36,123,81,125,55,54,43,38,59,108,50,58,54,45,38,111,64,36,123,113,125,36,123,113,43,113,125,114,112,112,62,111,60,100,101,102,32,110,40,120,41,58,103,108,111,98,97,108,32,108,59,114,61,112,43,112,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,113,43,40,112,43,80,41,42,40,108,45,120,41,43,81,43,80,32,105,102,32,120,60,108,32,101,108,115,101,32,112,43,112,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,40,112,43,80,41,42,40,120,45,108,41,43,80,59,108,61,120,59,114,101,116,117,114,110,32,114,59,39,39,97,39,39,112,61,99,104,114,40,52,48,41,59,80,61,99,104,114,40,52,49,41,59,113,61,99,104,114,40,57,49,41,59,81,61,99,104,114,40,57,51,41,59,102,61,99,104,114,40,49,50,51,41,59,70,61,99,104,114,40,49,50,53,41,59,108,61,52,59,112,114,105,110,116,32,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,80,43,112,43,80,43,112,43,80,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,112,43,80,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,44,109,97,112,40,110,44,109,97,112,40,108,97,109,98,100,97,32,120,58,111,114,100,40,120,41,45,52,56,44,115,116,114,40,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,109,97,112,40,108,97,109,98,100,97,32,99,58,36,123,98,125,54,48,48,36,123,98,125,43,40,115,116,114,40,99,45,57,57,41,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,50,41,43,36,123,98,125,57,57,53,48,48,36,123,98,125,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,49,48,41,32,105,102,32,99,62,57,57,32,101,108,115,101,32,115,116,114,40,99,41,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,50,41,43,36,123,98,125,53,48,48,36,123,98,125,41,44,91,96,43,91,46,46,46,96,40,102,61,36,123,102,125,41,40,41,96,93,46,109,97,112,40,99,61,62,99,46,99,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,65,116,40,41,41,43,96,93,41,41,91,58,58,45,49,93,43,36,123,98,125,57,57,57,57,54,36,123,98,125,41,41,44,36,123,91,46,46,46,39,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,80,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,80,112,112,80,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,39,93,46,106,111,105,110,96,43,96,125,36,123,113,125,96,93,46,109,97,112,40,115,61,62,99,40,52,51,41,46,114,101,112,101,97,116,40,115,46,99,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,65,116,40,41,41,43,99,40,52,54,41,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,41,46,109,97,116,99,104,40,47,46,123,49,44,50,53,51,125,47,103,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,99,40,49,48,41,43,81,41,41,125,41,40,41]))[::-1]+`99996`)),p+p+p+p+p+p+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+P+p+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nRZdT@Mw7K9M98Caa4aS5qPNCuieeC7PCGnjY3ecylYK6Kb785ztJF23tXBC6xrH33Zsp3/enpq3l/f3b7lNT8o6m9vZyebHdDptm@Zic3b/sJqsky2b/6w3t8t6UpfteZM26Sq9TKv0OU2atGLfk3q2ZelVWk0eV5PtWT15qF8eJju@wLWd1Sytyvp8W7YPr2/tetKW0@lyOm3O7361iRasrDwkWflMkAPoykOKlSuCZAbgZQANA326bNrH9StZjL@q@1fBC3wf7iv@tGySNb3r5dPt/XKynW/aewh5pgv@8tom7PT35nGd9Dju5gsrxCJNkHw3c46d/l091nWSsXThnAFaQEjBMCV3F875nJBEnx2ZGb/WgkuRcSu5M/i2GYcwuZQKd0B1DoECURb@GtgNrCimuLYkTWgpAQbmHBbNXU5Y3BEB@UEfqTSSmxxh43ghybaL@CzgXdHD59zoiHdeITogTVBeeOXWg4RSKAjKteKOSP5xlitLEQINDpEbQ7oVVwWqRwUGLBaENYhFfVZHMUwMyvW2eof1icjoj5lEUdFFj6lSGfmOac8ExVSQt9FziBtTBzvkFN4pTKQkpWTLL4KWXOC7ENELTYEHnoIs6IxQoAsCCla1CskBFjJkOu@AwYqdByG/mGuAVfa5GyP20bDxbkTLIeEYWyZipGSSai0P@fQuAggcih5IkQco0VQnWHTIg/UCBotYX2KY7gI9FPoBQ75j6Ap0n25kVCAGPABpI3Y8uRhlUZ0aygO4ZlwooV6rQTqOM//BEuthbBNQAyXUR31BBFGa5gANAH/ycggpQqFTq2OH4Jn68jOhiSkD/V6B@sEEWVJH3W@7dIb@t6H/Tddm/2UWzgashqZGSubnQoHPPjpW@J55HFSG6iKPrmSZn43ChAlVUOnE9juwRZJYDUMWR7VhlVKl7/cwzuws6Bxr4iP3v@L1iL8SDwjGLkzb4/m7u3HiDEV7QYzsAJMLd0v/7PxNZCk8VOU@uGisDy8Uhr8GvFbaOpq7hiYi5NCp0RPJw@1zHCEFGdG9EJXrroChfyHiUvhE5F9CBDWfa1SuS@Z@b4TDsYfXGW5HTgCrZncENEj9jNO2N7p9wZGUjVJfOa/OhI7IwQaPBBdNBkNIyn1NK2oUHQau8Te/zv1nwpheb7/rsHBj0tOv1hvGrufzmbzBLzDn7IIx3v8c3P8Y/Biqhvmn7@//AA)

### RAD

```
'''rpp>o<def n(x):global l;r=p+p+f+F+P+q+(p+P)*(l-x)+Q+P if x<l else p+p+f+F+P+(p+P)*(x-l)+P;l=x;return r;''a''p=chr(40);P=chr(41);q=chr(91);Q=chr(93);f=chr(123);F=chr(125);l=4;print p+p+p+p+p+p+P+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+P+f+F+P,map(n,map(lambda x:ord(x)-48,str().join(map(lambda c:`600`+(str(c-99).zfill(2)+`99500`.zfill(10) if c>99 else str(c).zfill(2)+`500`),[40,102,61,95,61,62,123,113,61,40,99,61,83,116,114,105,110,103,46,102,114,111,109,67,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,41,40,51,57,41,59,81,61,99,40,51,52,41,59,98,61,99,40,57,54,41,59,99,111,110,115,111,108,101,46,108,111,103,40,81,43,91,46,46,46,96,36,123,81,125,55,54,43,38,59,108,50,58,54,45,38,111,64,36,123,113,125,36,123,113,43,113,125,114,112,112,62,111,60,100,101,102,32,110,40,120,41,58,103,108,111,98,97,108,32,108,59,114,61,112,43,112,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,113,43,40,112,43,80,41,42,40,108,45,120,41,43,81,43,80,32,105,102,32,120,60,108,32,101,108,115,101,32,112,43,112,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,40,112,43,80,41,42,40,120,45,108,41,43,80,59,108,61,120,59,114,101,116,117,114,110,32,114,59,39,39,97,39,39,112,61,99,104,114,40,52,48,41,59,80,61,99,104,114,40,52,49,41,59,113,61,99,104,114,40,57,49,41,59,81,61,99,104,114,40,57,51,41,59,102,61,99,104,114,40,49,50,51,41,59,70,61,99,104,114,40,49,50,53,41,59,108,61,52,59,112,114,105,110,116,32,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,80,43,112,43,80,43,112,43,80,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,112,43,80,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,44,109,97,112,40,110,44,109,97,112,40,108,97,109,98,100,97,32,120,58,111,114,100,40,120,41,45,52,56,44,115,116,114,40,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,109,97,112,40,108,97,109,98,100,97,32,99,58,36,123,98,125,54,48,48,36,123,98,125,43,40,115,116,114,40,99,45,57,57,41,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,50,41,43,36,123,98,125,57,57,53,48,48,36,123,98,125,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,49,48,41,32,105,102,32,99,62,57,57,32,101,108,115,101,32,115,116,114,40,99,41,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,50,41,43,36,123,98,125,53,48,48,36,123,98,125,41,44,91,96,43,91,46,46,46,96,40,102,61,36,123,102,125,41,40,41,96,93,46,109,97,112,40,99,61,62,99,46,99,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,65,116,40,41,41,43,96,93,41,41,91,58,58,45,49,93,43,36,123,98,125,57,57,57,57,54,36,123,98,125,41,41,44,36,123,91,46,46,46,39,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,80,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,80,112,112,80,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,39,93,46,106,111,105,110,96,43,96,125,36,123,113,125,96,93,46,109,97,112,40,115,61,62,99,40,52,51,41,46,114,101,112,101,97,116,40,115,46,99,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,65,116,40,41,41,43,99,40,52,54,41,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,41,46,109,97,116,99,104,40,47,46,123,49,44,50,53,51,125,47,103,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,99,40,49,48,41,43,81,41,41,125,41,40,41]))[::-1]+`99996`)),p+p+p+p+p+p+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+P+p+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nRbZbtsw7FfyZmtWCsk6bMVtH/vsPhcFmubYMrhJ6nZAsJ/PSEpynMPtEMSxKN6kSMrtdL7fJ0nSbrf3m9v5Yjlapzs2@dlsXqfNqKnau222zZbZQ1Zn71m6zWr2I23GO5Y9ZvVotRztbpvRovlYjA58gWs3blhWV83drmoXn3/a9aitkmSaJNu72a821YJVtYckq94JcgA9ekixakmQzAF8CKBhoE9X23a1/iSL8Vd3/zp4ge/Tfc3fptt0Te9m@vY6n452k007h5DHuuQfn23Kbn5vVuu0xzGbvFghXrIUybOxc@zm73LVNGnOshfnDNACQgqGKZndO@dzQhJ9dmRm/EkLLkXOreTO4NvmHMLkUircAdU5BEpEWfhrYDewopji2pI0oaUEGJgLWDR3BWFxRwTkB32k0khuCoSN46Uk2y7i84B3ZQ9fcKMj3nmF6IA0QXnplVsPEkqhICjXijsi@cdZrixFCDQ4RG4M6VZclageFRiwWBLWIBb1WR3FMDEo19vqA9YnIqc/ZhJFRRc9pkrl5DumPRcUU0neRs8hbkwd7JBTeKcwkZKUki2/CFoKge9SRC80BR54SrKgc0KBLggoWNUqJAdYyJDpvAMGKw4ehPxirgFW@fduDNhHw8a7ES2HhGNsuYiRkkmqtSLk07sIIHAoeiBFHqBEU51g0SEP1gsYLGN9ict0F@ih0E8YigNDV6DHdCOjAnHBA5A24sBTiEEW1amhPIBrxoUS6rUapOM8818ssR6GNgF1oYT6qCtEEKVpDtAA8CcvLyFFKHRqdewQPFNffiY0MWWg3ytQP5ggS@qo@22XztD/NvS/6drsv8zC2YDV0NRIyf1cKPE5RscKPzKPg8pQXRTRlTz3s1GYMKFKKp3Yfie2SBKr4ZLFQW1YpVTpxz2MMzsPOoea@Mz9a7we8FfiAcHYhWl7Pn8PN06coWgviJEdYHLhbumfnb@JLIWHqtwXF4314YXC8NeA10pbR3PX0ESEHDo1eCJFuH3OI6QgI7oXonLdFXDpX4q4lD4RxVWIoOZ7jcp1yTzujXA49vQ6w@3ACWDVHI6ABqmfcdr2RrcvOJKyUeqa8@pM6Ii82OCR4KLJYAhJha9pRY2iw8A1/ubXhf9MGNLr7XcdFm5MevrV@szY02Qyls/4BeacfWGM9z8Hjz8Gv4bqy/zJfv8P)

### ><>

```
'rpp>o<def n(x):global l;r=p+p+f+F+P+q+(p+P)*(l-x)+Q+P if x<l else p+p+f+F+P+(p+P)*(x-l)+P;l=x;return r;'a'p=chr(40);P=chr(41);q=chr(91);Q=chr(93);f=chr(123);F=chr(125);l=4;print p+p+p+p+p+p+P+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+P+f+F+P,map(n,map(lambda x:ord(x)-48,str().join(map(lambda c:`600`+(str(c-99).zfill(2)+`99500`.zfill(10) if c>99 else str(c).zfill(2)+`500`),[40,102,61,95,61,62,123,113,61,40,99,61,83,116,114,105,110,103,46,102,114,111,109,67,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,41,40,51,57,41,59,81,61,99,40,51,52,41,59,98,61,99,40,57,54,41,59,99,111,110,115,111,108,101,46,108,111,103,40,81,43,91,46,46,46,96,36,123,81,125,55,54,43,38,59,108,50,58,54,45,38,111,64,36,123,113,125,36,123,113,43,113,125,114,112,112,62,111,60,100,101,102,32,110,40,120,41,58,103,108,111,98,97,108,32,108,59,114,61,112,43,112,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,113,43,40,112,43,80,41,42,40,108,45,120,41,43,81,43,80,32,105,102,32,120,60,108,32,101,108,115,101,32,112,43,112,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,40,112,43,80,41,42,40,120,45,108,41,43,80,59,108,61,120,59,114,101,116,117,114,110,32,114,59,39,39,97,39,39,112,61,99,104,114,40,52,48,41,59,80,61,99,104,114,40,52,49,41,59,113,61,99,104,114,40,57,49,41,59,81,61,99,104,114,40,57,51,41,59,102,61,99,104,114,40,49,50,51,41,59,70,61,99,104,114,40,49,50,53,41,59,108,61,52,59,112,114,105,110,116,32,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,80,43,112,43,80,43,112,43,80,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,112,43,80,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,44,109,97,112,40,110,44,109,97,112,40,108,97,109,98,100,97,32,120,58,111,114,100,40,120,41,45,52,56,44,115,116,114,40,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,109,97,112,40,108,97,109,98,100,97,32,99,58,36,123,98,125,54,48,48,36,123,98,125,43,40,115,116,114,40,99,45,57,57,41,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,50,41,43,36,123,98,125,57,57,53,48,48,36,123,98,125,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,49,48,41,32,105,102,32,99,62,57,57,32,101,108,115,101,32,115,116,114,40,99,41,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,50,41,43,36,123,98,125,53,48,48,36,123,98,125,41,44,91,96,43,91,46,46,46,96,40,102,61,36,123,102,125,41,40,41,96,93,46,109,97,112,40,99,61,62,99,46,99,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,65,116,40,41,41,43,96,93,41,41,91,58,58,45,49,93,43,36,123,98,125,57,57,57,57,54,36,123,98,125,41,41,44,36,123,91,46,46,46,39,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,80,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,80,112,112,80,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,39,93,46,106,111,105,110,96,43,96,125,36,123,113,125,96,93,46,109,97,112,40,115,61,62,99,40,52,51,41,46,114,101,112,101,97,116,40,115,46,99,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,65,116,40,41,41,43,99,40,52,54,41,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,41,46,109,97,116,99,104,40,47,46,123,49,44,50,53,51,125,47,103,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,99,40,49,48,41,43,81,41,41,125,41,40,41]))[::-1]+`99996`)),p+p+p+p+p+p+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+P+p+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P
```

`><>` outputs a newline in the middle with `'a'` so the python function would be separated from the rest of the code.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nRZdb@Iw7P1@Rd/WXMOUNB9tYNvjnrvnaRKMwY1TB6zbSej@PGc7SSnQbidEaRx/27GdLlcfr/v9VbPd3m1uXhbLZJ3u2PhXvXme1Uk9aW632TZbZvdZlb1n6Tar2M@0Hu1Y9pBVyWqZ7G7qZFF/LJIDX@DajWqWVZP6djdpFp9/mnXSTK5mV9vb@WuTasEmlYckm7wT5AB68JBikyVBMgfwPoCGgTY92Tar9SfZi7@q/VfBB3yf7iv@Ntuma3rXs7fnl1myG2@aFwh4pEv@8dmk7Pr3ZrVOOxzz8dQKMc1SJM9HzrHrv8tVXac5y6bOGaAFhBQMEzK/c85nhCS67MjM@KMWXIqcW8mdwbfNOYTJpVS4A6pzCJSIsvDXwG5gRTHFtSVpQksJMDAXsGjuCsLijgjID/pIpZHcFAgbx0tJtl3E5wHvyg6@4EZHvPMK0QFpgvLSK7ceJJRCQVCuFXdE8o@zXFmKEGhwiNwY0q24KlE9KjBgsSSsQSzqszqKYWJQrrPVB6xPRE5/zCSKijZ6TJXKyXdMey4oppK8jZ5D3Jg62CGn8E5hIiUpJVt@EbQUAt@liF5oCjzwlGRB54QCXRBQsKpVSA6wkCHTegcMVhw8CPnFXAOs8u/dGLCPho13I1oOCcfYchEjJZNUa0XIp3cRQOBQ9ECKPECJpjrBokMerBcwWMb6Ev10F@ih0E8YigNDW6DHdCOjAtHjAUgbceApxCCLatVQHsA140IJdVoN0nGe@S@WWA9Dm4DqKaEu6gIRRGmaAzQA/MnLPqQIhU6tjh2CZ@rLz4Qmpgx0ewXqBxNkSR11v23TGfrfhv43bZv9l1k4G7AamhopuZ8LJT7H6FjhR@ZxUBmqiyK6kud@NgoTJlRJpRPb78QWSWI19Fkc1IZVSpV@3MM4s/Ogc6iJz9y/xOsBfyUeEIxdmLbn8/dw48QZivaCGNkBJhfulu7Z@ZvIUnioyn1x0VgfXigMfw14rbR1NHcNTUTIoVODJ1KE2@c8QgoyojshKtdeAX3/UsSl9IkoLkIENd9rVK5N5nFvhMOxp9cZbgdOAKvmcAQ0SP2M07Yzun3BkZSNUpecV2tCR2Rvg0eCiyaDISQVvqYVNYoOA9f4m18X/jNhSK@333ZYuDHp6VbrE2OP4/FIPuEXmHN2yhjvfg4efwx@DVX9/D/2@38)

### Python 2

```python
def n(x):global l;r=p+p+f+F+P+q+(p+P)*(l-x)+Q+P if x<l else p+p+f+F+P+(p+P)*(x-l)+P;l=x;return r;
p=chr(40);P=chr(41);q=chr(91);Q=chr(93);f=chr(123);F=chr(125);l=4;print p+p+p+p+p+p+P+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+P+f+F+P,map(n,map(lambda x:ord(x)-48,str().join(map(lambda c:`600`+(str(c-99).zfill(2)+`99500`.zfill(10) if c>99 else str(c).zfill(2)+`500`),[40,102,61,95,61,62,123,113,61,40,99,61,83,116,114,105,110,103,46,102,114,111,109,67,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,41,40,51,57,41,59,81,61,99,40,51,52,41,59,98,61,99,40,57,54,41,59,99,111,110,115,111,108,101,46,108,111,103,40,81,43,91,46,46,46,96,36,123,81,125,55,54,43,38,59,108,50,58,54,45,38,111,64,36,123,113,125,36,123,113,43,113,125,114,112,112,62,111,60,100,101,102,32,110,40,120,41,58,103,108,111,98,97,108,32,108,59,114,61,112,43,112,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,113,43,40,112,43,80,41,42,40,108,45,120,41,43,81,43,80,32,105,102,32,120,60,108,32,101,108,115,101,32,112,43,112,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,40,112,43,80,41,42,40,120,45,108,41,43,80,59,108,61,120,59,114,101,116,117,114,110,32,114,59,39,39,97,39,39,112,61,99,104,114,40,52,48,41,59,80,61,99,104,114,40,52,49,41,59,113,61,99,104,114,40,57,49,41,59,81,61,99,104,114,40,57,51,41,59,102,61,99,104,114,40,49,50,51,41,59,70,61,99,104,114,40,49,50,53,41,59,108,61,52,59,112,114,105,110,116,32,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,112,43,80,43,112,43,80,43,112,43,80,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,112,43,80,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,43,102,43,70,43,80,44,109,97,112,40,110,44,109,97,112,40,108,97,109,98,100,97,32,120,58,111,114,100,40,120,41,45,52,56,44,115,116,114,40,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,109,97,112,40,108,97,109,98,100,97,32,99,58,36,123,98,125,54,48,48,36,123,98,125,43,40,115,116,114,40,99,45,57,57,41,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,50,41,43,36,123,98,125,57,57,53,48,48,36,123,98,125,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,49,48,41,32,105,102,32,99,62,57,57,32,101,108,115,101,32,115,116,114,40,99,41,46,122,102,105,108,108,40,50,41,43,36,123,98,125,53,48,48,36,123,98,125,41,44,91,96,43,91,46,46,46,96,40,102,61,36,123,102,125,41,40,41,96,93,46,109,97,112,40,99,61,62,99,46,99,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,65,116,40,41,41,43,96,93,41,41,91,58,58,45,49,93,43,36,123,98,125,57,57,57,57,54,36,123,98,125,41,41,44,36,123,91,46,46,46,39,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,80,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,102,70,80,112,112,80,112,80,80,102,70,112,80,80,39,93,46,106,111,105,110,96,43,96,125,36,123,113,125,96,93,46,109,97,112,40,115,61,62,99,40,52,51,41,46,114,101,112,101,97,116,40,115,46,99,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,65,116,40,41,41,43,99,40,52,54,41,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,41,46,109,97,116,99,104,40,47,46,123,49,44,50,53,51,125,47,103,41,46,106,111,105,110,40,99,40,49,48,41,43,81,41,41,125,41,40,41]))[::-1]+`99996`)),p+p+p+p+p+p+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P+f+F+P+p+p+P+p+P+P+f+F+p+P+P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nRZdc9ow7H2/Io/xYnp2/JGYrHvsc/rc2x0thZVdCjRld2x/nkmyHQIk7Y4jxLK@JUtytn92L5t1fjg8L5bJOt2z6c9m8/TYJE3V3m6zbbbM7rI6e8vSbVazr2kz2bPsPquT1TLZf2uSRfO@SI58gWs/aVhWV83tvmoXu9/tOmmrL9vb@UubasGq2kOSVW8EOYDuPaRYtSRI5gDeBdAw0KWrbbta78ha/NXdvw4e4Pt8X/PXx226pnfz@Pr0/Jjsp5v2GcKd6JK/79qU3fzarNZpj2M@nVkhZlmK5PnEOXbzd7lqmjRn2cw5A7SAkIJhOubfnfP5IIk@OzIz/qAFlyLnVnJn8G1zDmFyKRXugOocAiWiLPw1sBtYUUxxbUma0FICDMwFLJq7grC4IwLygz5SaSQ3BcLG8VKSbRfxecC7socvuNER77xCdECaoLz0yq0HCaVQEJRrxR2R/OMsV5YiBBocIjeGdCuuSlSPCgxYLAlrEIv6rI5imBiU6231EesTkdMfM4miooseU6Vy8h3TnguKqSRvo@cQN6YOdsgpvFOYSElKyZZfBC2FwHcpoheaAg88JVnQOaFAFwQUrGoVkgMsZMh03gGDFUcPQn4x1wCr/HM3RuyjYePdiJZDwjG2XMRIySTVWhHy6V0EEDgUPZAiD1CiqU6w6JAH6wUMlrG@xDDdBXoo9DOG4sjQFegp3cioQAx4ANJGHHkKMcqiOjWUB3DNuFBCvVaDdFxm/oMl1sPYJqAGSqiPukIEUZrmAA0Af/JyCClCoVOrY4fgmfryM6GJKQP9XoH6wQRZUkfdb7t0hv63of9N12b/ZRbOBqyGpkZK7udCic8pOlb4iXkcVIbqooiu5LmfjcKECVVS6cT2O7NFklgNQxZHtWGVUqWf9jDO7DzoHGviC/ev8XrEX4kHBGMXpu3l/D3eOHGGor0gRnaAyYW7pX92/iayFB6qch9cNNaHFwrDXwNeK20dzV1DExFy6NToiRTh9rmMkIKM6F6IynVXwNC/FHEpfSKKqxBBzecaleuSedob4XDs@XWG25ETwKo5HgENUj/jtO2Nbl9wJGWj1DXn1ZnQETnY4JHgoslgCEmFr2lFjaLDwDX@5teF/0wY0@vtdx0Wbkx6@tX6g7GH6XQif@AXmHN2xhjvfw6efgx@DNXD/IfDPw)

Python generates the brain-flak somewhat optimized, reusing the previous item on the stack, because otherwise the brain-flak code would be around a megabyte..

### Brain-Flak

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7d1NjhxFEAXgPaeYnbslOATnaNXCsAEhsWBr@eyNzQgMdnVXdjNVERnxeSzPaOwpZ2ZlvPh/8dMf73/9/Zf3P/92vZ7@@nX@/HH@8PHT778/n18u706nT58vr397Oi/nd9@/vH7vy1enfz6@fG/tJ0b@zdpTV3/mudWsrCd4RSnO59vv3Hjinefe/@o0fAqXhuc/y2o2/ofjVveflXljw3IVhCbr@NsZ/98CcZ3Q/9VJN55dX98OPHW@/d56h/Xe6B0NfOhbva2VWdJ734PR3e23z2@esfBdou3zLY1@lE0eupI73kvYqpa797OhTR6GlIfLaw49mQexe/oajyNQD88zieUc4C8M6MtCb@EmHi78FBgs3iPeI94j3iNz93Z@ZrAPPnIiNF2W3I@MKmuN17ax601sLXPyIzGyCn7AhV28b5RxqS0ng1kh8SQR1QPPPku@ITjmcbAMstLE1lls@92yu6jmLbKXxDIr1hWJJM5WRT56f8J7WTr4pmzj7laLOpN2NsXy0LMD4hKnZjGqHJXjgd0JZesz0lUXr@EOWSqPZjmy@B0xXlWh7KmqQlZzQOdWiK7f6rFLwhGSeoU9og8j7@ExDCrwDg5FV7JKVr0HeWa3je6iu2AmO5OsklWySlbJKlklq2SVrJJVHrX3YJd2aZd2aZcz7jI6J56l59YqxqeY9Kk/VqOag4UZx5EK4ttnDY8641FUV@tpTF9biZXAZ/jcC5@z8GLOV5ke4vNtMs9FTWIMxewsq8nvkfPP9JXjU8anjKkPnzJeN3zK@JTxKeNTxqdchU8Z19@cuMn2xcSHiQ@nSOmIieiASo3mvImRnSayi0EsSi2ZqfP2VGFNVEesmhn/aKP3piqadavOrTl398BNbLiatRiO@lu4BJfUUeWLTZqMFlVP9Zwdb@9mIojXpdxjvM41kVTthKo8VdIZdFoMl9ky6pGoDHevWMa9b3MezMAckL1SeIZa6rozPHtUOeWID@S4WRm9ylz5rkwsCqK5ormiuaK5orl6BtUMqBlQy6SWSZQEVsNqWK2@S32XiICIgIiAiICIgPoufkBVDmNVd6ruVN01rLrLxnuToKdcZEZkRhRdFD3X1CaYBJPaY9LE2Zrq1c89WLNjue874WEkn2xfNvhsGQD81firq@NNzzu@HQOXUzQ1Z6KI9cFvVX4RjsocyRyFZI6COWSHpqSFdTp3rSTox@w7po9pO7MnafKMPkOl/MIEWCVfIV8hfuhey1fIV5CBmfMV4f5/3fwEBIEgECS683bTqujWL33nnB7Lh@kYmHaK5hS3kdSSWlJLap0TyZ3ZH6FJ3EeaBEKSWlJLap2Tc2L/uZPupDvpTrqTztpZO2tn7aydtbM2abBnX6Aeet0/sPHNJzHqJ73bzfn80/UWlLyxmfgfUky8yjnX5QEOAYwdNP3@u53OhquvX3NXDtCAz98pmpAmpAlpQppQfRh9Oqs@zTO5jMaisWislL7b454b3y0hX2G0T0LX0DV0DV2Tah6WPDG9NWcene6iu@iuSXJcfKX8OifRjFj6hr6hb@gb9bRj1ffxnknYinJzjHpn@W2xXvq0Tw9Th26eflPqxuolzecrNMtIbxptXG/OnD4wfWAYeUzILCFD8dNS2@iNNHHo9Tg9HIDe4rjp5RbrIO5pSIJ7GmY7a5xqopr7M4yVz0tkjmjVus09eRgz3bBtq7RyJDtBHKjJ3c/VzV@blTPHzRIXqNCdLD/UTzP1yAHNaZHJD8kPiX/JD3n7@Tri5ePk48iufBwd6awT2SNt65NV5fOsZZuy5TPz9flu6KNy0nknvuf21/SEA/a54Y3LHehu0KHOolFD0KaucFs21DhVs/cuj82JEP2xS9GkrHVsy9HWpNyhXG2xnQbI0IAnDrvIElmaRJYuY9O8@S97MmqHvPn4ytzLtpUS91aSsjzJ9GICy4UjaSrwEmDJhnywjNvPY2TNHrWKZ7XIrqcS1AFlFeN4EX1ndJKqDMhej6OqrKqvk0NTqI9Qtwg/sGp1mdsy@31twryfhSkgSdR8wFbgC5jYOG2/DNyZYALvaDUoHIJDJTIIUCm5HQKR9M/pw@GXvzWyLXg2LuaHH336gZwOte/8YygKOyFW757pPpnJHln@2hmdPAz@sHDP3Pr2emM6PlNVaZVjDewapenB9qgHMnJuUeZsQNSqhs8HQnRgmN5JW4x0M63tfXk5vf76/NMfPn71x/lf3//uer3@8OOf)

### 4

```python
3.699996004050060003000009950060061500600955006006150060062500600240000099500600140000099500600615006004050060099500600615006008350060017000009950060015000009950060006000009950060011000009950060004000009950060046500600030000099500600150000099500600120000099500600100000099500600675006000500000995006009750060015000009950060067500600120000099500600010000099500600020000099500600415006004050060051500600575006004150060059500600815006006150060099500600405006005150060052500600415006005950060098500600615006009950060040500600575006005450060041500600595006009950060012000009950060011000009950060016000009950060012000009950060009000009950060002000009950060046500600090000099500600120000099500600040000099500600405006008150060043500600915006004650060046500600465006009650060036500600240000099500600815006002600000995006005550060054500600435006003850060059500600090000099500600505006005850060054500600455006003850060012000009950060064500600365006002400000995006001400000995006002600000995006003650060024000009950060014000009950060043500600140000099500600260000099500600150000099500600130000099500600130000099500600625006001200000995006006050060001000009950060002000009950060003000009950060032500600110000099500600405006002100000995006004150060058500600040000099500600090000099500600120000099500600985006009750060009000009950060032500600090000099500600595006001500000995006006150060013000009950060043500600130000099500600435006000300000995006004350060070500600435006008050060043500600140000099500600435006004050060013000009950060043500600805006004150060042500600405006000900000995006004550060021000009950060041500600435006008150060043500600805006003250060006000009950060003000009950060032500600210000099500600605006000900000995006003250060002000009950060009000009950060016000009950060002000009950060032500600130000099500600435006001300000995006004350060003000009950060043500600705006004350060080500600435006004050060013000009950060043500600805006004150060042500600405006002100000995006004550060009000009950060041500600435006008050060059500600090000099500600615006002100000995006005950060015000009950060002000009950060017000009950060018000009950060015000009950060011000009950060032500600150000099500600595006003950060039500600975006003950060039500600130000099500600615006009950060005000009950060015000009950060040500600525006004850060041500600595006008050060061500600995006000500000995006001500000995006004050060052500600495006004150060059500600140000099500600615006009950060005000009950060015000009950060040500600575006004950060041500600595006008150060061500600995006000500000995006001500000995006004050060057500600515006004150060059500600030000099500600615006009950060005000009950060015000009950060040500600495006005050060051500600415006005950060070500600615006009950060005000009950060015000009950060040500600495006005050060053500600415006005950060009000009950060061500600525006005950060013000009950060015000009950060006000009950060011000009950060017000009950060032500600130000099500600435006001300000995006004350060013000009950060043500600130000099500600435006001300000995006004350060013000009950060043500600805006004350060013000009950060043500600805006004350060013000009950060043500600805006004350060080500600435006000300000995006004350060070500600435006008050060043500600030000099500600435006007050060043500600130000099500600435006008050060043500600805006004350060003000009950060043500600705006004350060080500600435006000300000995006004350060070500600435006008050060044500600100000099500600975006001300000995006004050060011000009950060044500600100000099500600975006001300000995006004050060009000009950060097500600100000099500600985006000100000995006009750060032500600210000099500600585006001200000995006001500000995006000100000995006004050060021000009950060041500600455006005250060056500600445006001600000995006001700000995006001500000995006004050060041500600465006000700000995006001200000995006000600000995006001100000995006004050060010000009950060097500600130000099500600405006000900000995006009750060010000009950060098500600010000099500600975006003250060099500600585006003650060024000009950060098500600260000099500600545006004850060048500600365006002400000995006009850060026000009950060043500600405006001600000995006001700000995006001500000995006004050060099500600455006005750060057500600415006004650060023000009950060003000009950060006000009950060009000009950060009000009950060040500600505006004150060043500600365006002400000995006009850060026000009950060057500600575006005350060048500600485006003650060024000009950060098500600260000099500600465006002300000995006000300000995006000600000995006000900000995006000900000995006004050060049500600485006004150060032500600060000099500600030000099500600325006009950060062500600575006005750060032500600020000099500600090000099500600160000099500600020000099500600325006001600000995006001700000995006001500000995006004050060099500600415006004650060023000009950060003000009950060006000009950060009000009950060009000009950060040500600505006004150060043500600365006002400000995006009850060026000009950060053500600485006004850060036500600240000099500600985006002600000995006004150060044500600915006009650060043500600915006004650060046500600465006009650060040500600030000099500600615006003650060024000009950060003000009950060026000009950060041500600405006004150060096500600935006004650060010000009950060097500600130000099500600405006009950060061500600625006009950060046500600995006000500000995006009750060015000009950060067500600120000099500600010000099500600020000099500600655006001700000995006004050060041500600415006004350060096500600935006004150060041500600915006005850060058500600455006004950060093500600435006003650060024000009950060098500600260000099500600575006005750060057500600575006005450060036500600240000099500600985006002600000995006004150060041500600445006003650060024000009950060091500600465006004650060046500600395006001300000995006001300000995006001300000995006001300000995006001300000995006001300000995006001300000995006008050060013000009950060080500600805006000300000995006007050060013000009950060080500600805006000300000995006007050060013000009950060080500600805006000300000995006007050060013000009950060080500600805006000300000995006007050060080500600130000099500600130000099500600805006001300000995006008050060080500600030000099500600705006001300000995006008050060080500600395006009350060046500600070000099500600120000099500600060000099500600110000099500600965006004350060096500600260000099500600365006002400000995006001400000995006002600000995006009650060093500600465006001000000995006009750060013000009950060040500600160000099500600615006006250060099500600405006005250060051500600415006004650060015000009950060002000009950060013000009950060002000009950060097500600170000099500600405006001600000995006004650060099500600050000099500600975006001500000995006006750060012000009950060001000009950060002000009950060065500600170000099500600405006004150060041500600435006009950060040500600525006005450060041500600415006004650060007000009950060012000009950060006000009950060011000009950060040500600415006004650060010000009950060097500600170000099500600995006000500000995006004050060047500600465006002400000995006004950060044500600505006005350060051500600260000099500600475006000400000995006004150060046500600070000099500600120000099500600060000099500600110000099500600405006009950060040500600495006004850060041500600435006008150060041500600415006002600000995006004150060040500600415004
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1VmJjhshDP2jytzw/x@Wbjdjq35jkznItllphWCwDc8nTn480q86vv4qUaZC9DVSoj9/YzynNTzHUfS8xucYs9oesknNzHG9p42saS5FTb////oa9FctMlfzHsAyRD0lfey28dBEo5m8eDfwJDim/poBmbLNS9Pfy7a/B9DHcOijTT/6C/pNbskOvQOcvmSoM5RpTBGp5i7kAdomDU/eDGoEzRTHsY2pmmbM7KK@TykA0iYtdQ0WXKEwxh3IiyaHq9Y8PSO4Ghz1GBFfYM4LfSfNphwY8DJ0xCvAaVM0rYyVHoPpUgwzmMrcrtg/2MdhN58ENWsjxE4G0Aja9jLZy430vNNUd7zMIDnChAs7StRkcFE2VQdy4RpsKQJfPaJuEFJprpJpkIGIBJvFwH5CUTc1gtAXW1GOBpzQxJYKzB27BvQwa/dp1Ag28sUUnGBkt8T14FQrw0zgIExyHyPdndxLS7gPm7tTMp0U0uZCvPLhHHcuMpA7rdBCxmzpCGu0VEpyrmT7CSuzOLnwTOEK7nMtFr1zeZdplm7D@cWoepDsvzyUkGXzGSLvjWSaMlZFl5iAnctuMqsjqN4kKtuJu9h1LTrJqeKO0544YoXb12mKcoICvBaoTZ8gU68W7fw7NSD@zluAueEjJ0M2vMRlV/Rc0QvWOpKHmq23mGblJRafYzaV1Ed2XXUSUzi4ZJ17GL/v2lJHQEl0rpDHNyHCsLSEv2VgH2NIawwn6KDJ3RLuipztorzoHTqHg93eGQE3ljmSPsu5eItHrGCxcsPx9k5gLabF7nITdrgQB9g3oBvCI8dS9nChXxPYmt1OvGifYKcelxdmmg41rhZOO02Xu@0u7WOonPv9JApp2GHgTum2C3/1RmsViNaELUhybvSC1gM@pUX4vL2TZl/lpO3IST8gnnrYZYdu4Vthpxc6ArWDpTBtUNNAnxiejdgQKfZPIMwVf4d5AypHa9Jd8xnGI4VFfjx@Aw)

Answer (score 4):

## 4. ><> → JavaScript → Python 2 → Foo

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish)

```
'rpp>o<(f=_=>console.log(`print(${String.fromCharCode(39,34,92,39)}rpp>o<(f=${f})()${String.fromCharCode(34,39)})`))()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X72ooMAu30YjzTbe1i45P684PydVLyc/XSOhoCgzr0RDpTq4BMhI10srys91zkgscs5PSdUwttQxNtGxNNIxttSshZugUp1Wq6mhiUOLCVixZoImUMn//wA)

I've added the classic wrapping string literal, appending `'rpp>o<` to the start, and editing it into the center part too.

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org)

```javascript
(f=_=>console.log(`print(${(a=String.fromCharCode)(39,34,92,39)}rpp>o<(f=${f})()${a(34,39)})`))()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f9fI8023tYuOT@vOD8nVS8nP10joaAoM69EQ6VaI9E2uATITtdLK8rPdc5ILHIGatHUMLbUMTbRsTTSMbbUrC0qKLDLtwGaolKdVqupoalSnagBlAVJaSZoAgX@/wcA)

I've shortened the `String.fromCharCode` part as per comments on the last answer. I know this challenge isn't actually code-golf, but it makes me feel better.

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/)

```python
print('"\'rpp>o<(f=_=>console.log(`print(${(a=String.fromCharCode)(39,34,92,39)}rpp>o<(f=${f})()${a(34,39)})`))()"')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EQ10pRr2ooMAu30YjzTbe1i45P684PydVLyc/XSMBokSlWiPRNrgEyE7XSyvKz3XOSCxyzk9J1dQwttQxNtGxNNIxttSshZuiUp1Wq6mhqVKdqAGUBUlpJmgCBZTUNbn@/wcA)

Added the `\'` for the start of the ><> quine.

## [Foo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Foo)

```python
"'rpp>o<(f=_=>console.log(`print(${(a=String.fromCharCode)(39,34,92,39)}rpp>o<(f=${f})()${a(34,39)})`))()"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vP//9fSb2ooMAu30YjzTbe1i45P684PydVLyc/XSOhoCgzr0RDpVoj0Ta4BMhO10srys91zkgscs5PSdXUMLbUMTbRsTTSMbbUrIWbolKdVqupoalSnagBlAVJaSZoAgWUuP7/BwA)

Answer (score 4):

## 6. ><> → JavaScript → brainfuck → Python 2 → Brain-Flak → Foo

Obligatory Brain-Flak answer.

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish)

```
'rpp>o<(f=_=>{q=(c=String.fromCharCode)(39);Q=c(34);s=c(92);console.log([...`print map(lambda x:${q}(${q}+ord(x)*${q}()${q}+${q})${q},${q+Q+s+q}rpp>o<(f=${f})()${Q+q}),${q}{({}<>)<>}<>${q}`].map(s=>c(43).repeat(s.charCodeAt())+c(46)).join())})()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU7LisMwDPyVHgqV1kWHpiy0iQ2lXxD2uJSt13k0JYkdO4eC8bendlj2MtKMRtI0nXssy84aI3QBDf/hwk8cFP@abTe21Fg9XB/SXnVVI2QnzEuuIDti7mI9HTBXenS6r6nXLXwT0d3ExXkzSAO9HH4ruXmdt34KkIBpW8ELP1YBVyXB2u0jsJI5NoX/OFvfBEzGMqqYHMGDD4XAQkRM/H6j9MtxoeCYIdna1HIGR@ov9mUGRBaHn4j01N0YaTq6LG8)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org)

```javascript
(f=_=>{q=(c=String.fromCharCode)(39);Q=c(34);s=c(92);console.log([...`print map(lambda x:${q}(${q}+ord(x)*${q}()${q}+${q})${q},${q+Q+s+q}rpp>o<(f=${f})()${Q+q}),${q}{({}<>)<>}<>${q}`].map(s=>c(43).repeat(s.charCodeAt())+c(46)).join())})()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU7BasMwDP2VHnqQ5s2HphS6xIbSLwg7jtG6TtKlJLFjm1Ew/vZMDr086T09Se@h/pTXrrfhYzJNuyzQiYuQcRagxVdw/XTnnTPj@Ve5MxkQiiOWtdBQ7LH0VI87LLWZvBlaPpg7fHPOr5YWw2ZUFgY13hq1eX5u45wgAzOugSe@rQKuSoa1eydgNfNsTs5aaSqKs41dwmysScXsSBFiqiRWkjDz6w/Pv7yQGvYFctfaVgXwXL9inwIgMhoeEPnD9BPRfHRZ/gE)

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck)

```javascript
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VxbDgJBCPv3Kmv2TmpiYkz8MPH84xVmH0Bb6v/aDmUAWfD@vb0@z9/jPcaS/FmvyyKMmX28CnPOoCbzSoDLt/Q8Yi43PWNnwOUcCUKbmqB0FHn62YB7uYl3unl1czZqiN2JvIVkpbuX34xypud@baxzBllAvyxDQSRLGHhB@SBOOM1ifnW5sQY8zdwpZ0N0btS2BjWmbG9qKxBJ2uiQ62vg8jhLNibpVADtKeC1BXZxP3DgoN5GhibovwlghSfW3F4RehIpz5Dv0jPeL3RAvNpB1wjQP1RDKUXLj@deHd4SuJdUgOo5J5mo2MDYnnNivvwnIc8963d61DHQ8uHCe35PvnTYiXz@/J7jAH8pa6V7RHwryB2XrR8wvCVErFux62YGhlSXkBXTI//BgE1H/lukG7Uyz7Wj0yakUzruuEhiSK16EiVWazREu6rk2CoGH4yAPYvpiSM@n6YI8tESRC@0gF/bTEzZfpzo8qZc/BPb5/HOMBDxrjvDDQJWVLbvWz9h2D/ZS5XHOXHXfDD8rM7cZZYq/Y/FMAbtamw@jw8g77671OHXyxh/)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/)

```python
print map(lambda x:'('+ord(x)*'()'+')','"\'rpp>o<(f=_=>{q=(c=String.fromCharCode)(39);Q=c(34);s=c(92);console.log([...`print map(lambda x:${q}(${q}+ord(x)*${q}()${q}+${q})${q},${q+Q+s+q}rpp>o<(f=${f})()${Q+q}),${q}{({}<>)<>}<>${q}`].map(s=>c(43).repeat(s.charCodeAt())+c(46)).join())})()"'),'{({}<>)<>}<>'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU7BasMwDP2VUgqS5uBDUwZdYkPpF4Qet7FmTtJ2JLHj@NAR/O2ZHbaxwy5P0tOT3jOf7qr77Twbe@vdqisNtmX3XpWr@xMgMG0rvNMDIAEDggTWL2CNkTrHRrwJOQ0ClTi5cH3hjdXd8Vrao65qwnRPWSEUpjvKxlD3W8qU7kfd1rzVF3zmnJ//sd1Mg8cIP@YLQQsTYemSAKxgIxv8b5zN1HiKwiKwFBV@wsnnknIZMM7nVx69RiEV7lLitjZ16XDk6jv2wSERC8tHIv6hb30Y49M1UAJ/v8E8fwE)

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7d1NasJQFIbhuatwZgJ1B0FwHcWBDgSxdOBUuvbbbkFqjPc7DwGHCe93fu75iXq6HS/f2/PX8dra52YYxv9f4@Zj/Zw7zXvP97xqkKKkcwbjPE/Ps9vSRAmK0rBOHVCXPdPLk6wnD4lafVomab4FEwnnZ9KRIMWIL1frFCp5jeoY61lsLp7@5yFLWbovi2RFjRmVDLCUNcQ9f6d14jbldc@VQ@QIjAixYjSxoJiIxpSrVEImkM1kLVs4XAiTab1ngkMlSTMc@GpaSvzUraGWp37uk32fECd@ccg/cfbMbxOE1PnDM95PTXUCdpy5@VJ8Y8eZ2QeIRpz4RSIPxdk7v3jEbl5LAzrSED9SlFUo7UZNrFlJD8Q3WTNls25qKZ50pmwtd8p1/B8nfj0uRfGby9FVXLG/uhY7zlr8vVP4/Tx8NuO0q7pPrW7thHhI@E8b5zBSJzOr4XAeUlD9hQpHVVLvjqPBo/aq2bF7N9TkyvxKN4GsMqP/QZLf1Hy86/E7Hdb34f4z7cZp9/e5aq1t978)

I've excluded the code since it's 41568 bytes and reaches the character limit of the answer. The code is similar to the brainfuck code and is in the format:

```python
[
  '( ()*byte value )', Repeated for each character
] '{({}<>)<>}<>'      To reverse the stack
```

## [Foo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Foo)

```python
"'rpp>o<(f=_=>{q=(c=String.fromCharCode)(39);Q=c(34);s=c(92);console.log([...`print map(lambda x:${q}(${q}+ord(x)*${q}()${q}+${q})${q},${q+Q+s+q}rpp>o<(f=${f})()${Q+q}),${q}{({}<>)<>}<>${q}`].map(s=>c(43).repeat(s.charCodeAt())+c(46)).join())})()"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU7BasMwDL3vK0opTJqLDksZdIkNpV8Qdhxj9Zyk60gix86hYPztmR3GLk96T0/S65iXZfvorFVcQSc/pQqTBCPfZncbr9Q5Hs7f2p25aRGKI5a1NFAcsPSpHp@xNDx67lvq@QrvRHSxaXHeDNpCr4evRm/ur7swRcgg2DVwx6dVwFXJsHb7BKIWXkzxP84udBGzsU4qZkcMEGKlsFIJM798UP7lpTJwKJBca1s9gyfzF/s0A6JIwxdE@uHbmGg@un1Yll8)

Answer (score 4):

## 7. ><> → JavaScript → RAD → brainfuck → Python 2 → Brain-Flak → Foo

### ><>

```
'rpp>o<(f=_=>{q=(c=String.fromCharCode)(39);Q=c(34);s=c(92);console.log(q+[...`print map(lambda x:${q}(${q}+ord(x)*${q}()${q}+${q})${q},${q+Q+s+q}rpp>o<(f=${f})()${Q+q}),${q}{({}<>)<>}<>${q}`].map(s=>c(43).repeat(s.charCodeAt())+c(46)).join()+q)})()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7LasMwEEV/JYtAZ6oyizgUUluCkC8wXZaSKLKduNjWy4uA0Le7kgnZnJm5c@fR9f6@LG/OGKEr6PiZi2A5KP49u366Uef0eLpLd9JNi1AcsKy5gmKPpU/xsMNS6cnroaVB38CyHyK6mDQ6b0ZpYJDjtZGbx9c22AgZTLsGHvi@CrgqGWv2kcBq5pmNr4e2oYuYjXVSMTtigBArgZVIzPXll/Itz4WCfYHkWtPKGTyp5@PHGRBZan4i0p/uJ0BmMa9dln8)

### JavaScript

```javascript
(f=_=>{q=(c=String.fromCharCode)(39);Q=c(34);s=c(92);console.log(q+[...`print map(lambda x:${q}(${q}+ord(x)*${q}()${q}+${q})${q},${q+Q+s+q}rpp>o<(f=${f})()${Q+q}),${q}{({}<>)<>}<>${q}`].map(s=>c(43).repeat(s.charCodeAt())+c(46)).join()+q)})()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7LasMwEEV/JYssZqp2FnEopLYEIV9guiylUWU7dbCtJyUg9O2uZLo5M3PnzuMuf6VXbjThZdFdv64w8C8uouWg@Htw43Kjwen58iPdJRsQqhPWLVdQHbH2OZ4OWCu9eD31NOkbWPZBRFeTR8NulgYmOX93cvd420eboIBp18EDnzYBN6Vgy54zWMs8s8kZI3STH9rHIWExtlnF4kgRYmoENiKz1NdPKrc8FwqOFZLrTS8DeFL/j58DILLcfEWkux4XQGaxrF3XPw)

### RAD

```
'++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VzLDYNQDLt3EQ5U7FSpE3R/ia7AL47tuHewX/7kJf19vvu@rODf9l5XY0z08TrEeQQVzAsAh5f0cUQsNz9hI@AwR6LQTU9Quot8@NkCvzzFGy5e35zNGmIvIp8h2Wnu7Z7RzvTZ19YaZ5EE/MsyFkSxhMEXlG/ilNNs5teXG3vAYeKGnI3RuFnbGtKYtr2ps0AiaWNCru@Bw3G2bEzKaYG0p8DXFrjE/caBi3obCJ2wfxPQKl5Y57GK0pNYWYZ9l17Rv9gB@WoHXyFQf6iyd7VK@VWbJ5/5T7jFSK@rATVzWL5RO3NYvEfKHFbxs7lzlI6BUd/Q2n5WLZr5wsQB5zAeTQ@K@NGgdlyO/ojho0LGupW7blZgKOWEqphZSSgGHLqSMCLduJV5qR2TNimNMnEnRZJCavVTEbBakyE6VUuJrWbwxQjcs6KZONKzaYkgX62C6oUbcrdFYtr240yXS@3in9m@UXaaiYhP3WkeELCqsv3c@olD/mArdR7n5F3zkXZemB8oMH34pa3/UVnGYNw3gJ7FF5DPvYDV4bflte9/)

### brainfuck

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.,+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VxJbsNADLv3Ky78p6ZAgSJADgXyfvcL3kSRFHO3ydFujZTH39fv6@f9/dy2BfxbP5fFGBN9vA5x7kEF8wLA4SW9HxHLzU/YCDjMkSh00xOUriLvfrbALw/xhovXN2ezhtiTyEdIdpp7u2e0M733tbXGWSQB/7KMBVEsYfAF5Ys45TSb@fXlxh5wmLghZ2M0bta2hjSmbW/qKJBI2piQ63vgcJwtG5NyWiDtKfC1BU5xv3Dgot4GQifs3wS0ihfWeayi9CRWlmHfpVf0L3ZAvtrBVwjUH6rsXa1SftXmyWf@E24x0utqQM0clm/UzhwW75Eyh1X8bO4cpWNg1De0tp9Vi2a@MHHAOYxH04MifjSoHZejP2L4qJCxbuWumxUYSjmhKmZWEooBh64kjEg3bmVeasekTUqjTNxJkaSQWv1UBKzWZIhO1VJiqxl8MQL3rGgmjvRsWiLIV6ugeuGG3G2RmLb9ONPlUrv4Z7ZvlJ1mIuJTd5oHBKyqbD@3fuKQP9hKncc5edd8pJ0X5gcKTG9@aet/VJYxGPcNoGfxBeRzL2B1@PVj2/4B)

### Python 2

```python
print map(lambda x:'('+ord(x)*'()'+')','"\'rpp>o<(f=_=>{q=(c=String.fromCharCode)(39);Q=c(34);s=c(92);console.log(q+[...`print map(lambda x:${q}(${q}+ord(x)*${q}()${q}+${q})${q},${q+Q+s+q}rpp>o<(f=${f})()${Q+q}),${q}{({}<>)<>}<>${q}`].map(s=>c(43).repeat(s.charCodeAt())+c(46)).join()+q)})()"'),'{({}<>)<>}<>'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU7LasMwEPyVEAK7Wxkd4lBIbRlCvsDk2JZG9SNJsS1Z8iFF6NtdybSlh15md2d3Z0Z/Tlc1bOdZm9swrXqpsZP9ey1X9ydAYMrUeKcHQAIGBAmsX8BoXagcW/EmCjcKrMRpCt8X3hrVH6/SHFXdEKZ7ykpRYbqjzIa631JWqcGqruGduuDInjnn53@MN270GOHHfiFoYSIsXRKAlcyy0f8G2rjWUzwsA0vxwjt0Pi8oLwLG@fzKo5cVRYW7lLhpdCMntLz6Dn6YkIiF5SMR/1C3AYmNFGXXQAn81YN5/gI)

### Brain-Flak

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7d0xbsJAEIXhnlPQ2ZbCDRAS54hSkAIJJaKgRZx9kzuEjdk3n5AoMf97M7M7swZ/3k6X6@78ffpq7X2a5@Xvr2V62z7nk/p@5mu@apCipHMGY5@r5/m2NlGCojSssw@oy54Z5UnuqUOyVp@WSZrvYCJhfyYdCVKM@HK1TqFS16iOsZ5jvXjGn4es5fRYjmRljRmVCrCWG/JevNM68TTl/66rhqgRGBFixWhiQTEZjUk09OYcWcOEampFkOtOMnEhTKZ1rw4Ou3Ga4cBX0yn5U3cPtT71c6/sN5k48ctD8YnT7F/8IDWjqBgZ/dS0T8COM7deym/sODP7ANmIE79MFKE4R@eXj9jNa2lARxriR4qyCqWzURNrLumBxCY3U07WTS3lk86U12qnWif@ceLX41IUv7kcXeUV/@1rseOsxT86hf/Pw@dknHZVz1Oru52QDwnPBbIOI7Uycw2H9ZCC9l@ocFQlde84Gjz2XjU7dveGmlyZX@kmkFVm9BwkqzLH6Zen6@t/22X62N7n@2N/WPaH3/dNa213/AE)

### Foo

```
"'rpp>o<(f=_=>{q=(c=String.fromCharCode)(39);Q=c(34);s=c(92);console.log(q+[...`print map(lambda x:${q}(${q}+ord(x)*${q}()${q}+${q})${q},${q+Q+s+q}rpp>o<(f=${f})()${Q+q}),${q}{({}<>)<>}<>${q}`].map(s=>c(43).repeat(s.charCodeAt())+c(46)).join()+q)})()"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7LasMwEEX3/YoQAp2pghZ1KKS2BCFfYLoMIVFlO02xPXp4ERD6dlcyoZszM3fuPDqieV6/OmMkVdCJi5DBCtDia3L38cY7R8PxR7kjNS1CsceyFhqKHZY@xf07lppGT33Le7qBZSfO@dWk0Wk1KAO9Gr4btXp8boKNkMHINfDAt0XARclYsm0Cq5lnNv4/tAldxGysk4rZEQOEWEmsZGKur2eeb3khNewK5K41rZrAc/18/DABIkvND0T@S/cRkFnMa9cv8/wH)

Answer (score 4):

## 8. ><> → Wumpus → JavaScript → RAD → brainfuck → Python 2 → Brain-Flak → Foo

Adding in another 2D language, Wumpus.

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish)

```
'rppp:1->o#13&;l2:6-&o@(f=_=>{q=(c=String.fromCharCode)(39);Q=c(34);s=c(92);console.log(q+[...`print map(lambda x:(ord(x)*${q}()${q},),${q+Q+s+q}rppp:1->o#13&;l2:6-&o@${Q+s}n${Q}(f=${f})()${Q+q}),${q}{({}<>)<>}<>${q}`].map(s=>c(43).repeat(s.charCodeAt())+c(46)).join()+q)})()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/NasMwEIRfJRCT7FaJIHEIxI5ES57A9FhKo8h24mJbfz4EhJ7dlUqPvcywDN/ubNu5xzyvrda62G25Wu7yVdnvi@N2pV6hZV@Me8NAsvfJduOdtlYNl4ewF1U3CPkJy4pJyA9YuuinPZZSjU71De3VHQz5oJRedUSnxSA09GK41WLxLEDZGp74knkTAJNucBONVMQRE/7vk/mYhjFaiNUy3wZMbBWBXzh48OHM8cyjpvn6SdNVx7iEQ47UNroREzgq/154mwCRxPCISL9VNwISg2ntPP8A)

This now prints an extra `"` before the Wumpus code.

## [Wumpus](https://github.com/m-ender/wumpus)

```
"#13&;l2:6-&o@(f=_=>{q=(c=String.fromCharCode)(39);Q=c(34);s=c(92);console.log(q+[...`print map(lambda x:(ord(x)*${q}()${q},),${q+Q+s+q}rppp:1->o#13&;l2:6-&o@${Q+s}n${Q}(f=${f})()${Q+q}),${q}{({}<>)<>}<>${q}`].map(s=>c(43).repeat(s.charCodeAt())+c(46)).join()+q)})()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/dasJAEIVfRWyQma4uaEQwcZcWnyD0spS6bhKrJNm/SIVlnz3dLb3pzTkMh2/mzPe913c3TfOndb4ou02xWy3UC7Tsk3FvGEj2NtrrcKGtVf3xS9ijqhuEfI9lxSTkWyxd9P0GS6kGp7qGduoChrxTSk86ouOsFxo60Z9rMXsUoGwND3zOvAmASZe4jEYq4ogJVmtdrFdc/euT@ZiGIVqI1TLfBkxsFYFfOHjw4cDxwKOm@fRB01XHuIRtjtQ2uhEjOCr/XngdAZHEcIdIb@o6ABKDae00/QA)

Similar to the `><>` quine, this wraps a string literal around the code and printsonly the javascript section

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org)

```javascript
(f=_=>{q=(c=String.fromCharCode)(39);Q=c(34);s=c(92);console.log(q+[...`print map(lambda x:(ord(x)*${q}()${q},),${q+Q+s+q}rppp:1->o#13&;l2:6-&o@${Q+s}n${Q}(f=${f})()${Q+q}),${q}{({}<>)<>}<>${q}`].map(s=>c(43).repeat(s.charCodeAt())+c(46)).join()+q)})()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY/vasIwFMVfRbDIvYsNaEWwNcHhE5R9HGNmaesqbZImYQghz96lY1/O4XLu7/55iB/hpO2Nz5Vu2nmGjn0yHiYGkr1526s77awer9/CXlMDQnHCqmYSigNWLvlpj5XUyumhpYO@w0TeKaU3k1C/GoWBQYxfjVg9S9C2gSe@ZGGKgItucZuM1MSRKVpjTLnLuV7vik017MtjvtGXLKQ0qmQxnZaFLuLC1gn4g2OAEM8czzzpUt8@6LLVMS7hUCC1rWmFB0fl/wuvHhBJCo@I9KF7BUgmXMbO8y8)

## [RAD](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/rad)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VzLrcMwDLt3kR7y0J0KdIK3P5CukE9JkxR7bkJ9aFmS5fy/P/v@3Mi/19@2BWOy1VthziOoZLkIcHxLH0fkypZnbAYcRyUJ36wJSneRVZdb9KYpbPQryGeEPPxfiI0A6EBb/VheLJdAps1PY2YiXnj25CN37aG53@Htdu6hW1bSz@DJFEfy3DB/M9rViHh62eNNHLiYi@Vbl8SvAaeZm6KbIrlVG6DWmLFd7LNAJttGUFYvBseTOfIIw84LVECSWpCeHLSUZinB8Yl6TSDreGOflxVQTaKYEX@c6Li@1AH1codcI0gXqupdLah8aHrq0X/CaWp7XQtQO7GZG7U7samrUic2E5OkTmyOndjsGbf/nltPW3saGAPKDc2egE5PwlVCq9WdXyHOROww/DXADsNT0ToMv9K7MzOwsAzHH740TCn3Vxqk5aRh/GjTqWWxMSkbd5rCOGyteS4idh9sBJ3qpcbWMHgwgvYsbie6/DhtEeTRLkBfaBJftkzM2NOv0Mu7cfEv7D5X74wLCT71zviAgIXa7efmTxr2J7M0eQpd9xqV9eKlrQMHSX/8UsR3ehd@1HhqDeDHeIDwPReIUv71fOz7Fw)

I'm excluding very long sections of code from the chain, so as to not fill up the answer.

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VxbTsRADPvnKkV7J0BCQkh8IHH@coU@1h7b8X5v6zw8mSST6fvv29fP59/H975v5N/jdduCMdnqrTDnEVSyXAQ4vqWPI3JlyzM2A46jkoRv1gSlu8iqyy160xQ2@hXkM0Ie/i/ERgB0oK2eLC@WSyDT5qcxMxEvPHvykbv20Nzv8HY799AtK@ln8GSKI3lumL8Z7WpEPL3s8SYOXMzF8q1L4teA08xN0U2R3KoNUGvM2C72WSCTbSMoqxeD48kceYRh5wUqIEktSE8OWkqzlOD4RL0mkHW8sc/LCqgmUcyIP050XF/qgHq5Q64RpAtV9a4WVD40PfXoP@E0tb2uBaid2MyN2p3Y1FWpE5uJSVInNsdObPaM23/PraetPQ2MAeWGZk9ApyfhKqHV6s6vEGcidhj@GmCH4aloHYZf6d2ZGVhYhuMPXxqmlPsrDdJy0jB@tOnUstiYlI07TWEcttY8FxG7DzaCTvVSY2sYPBhBexa3E11@nLYI8mgXoC80iS9bJmbs6Vfo5d24@Bd2n6t3xoUEn3pnfEDAQu32c/MnDfuTWZo8ha57jcp68dLWgYOkT34p4ju9Cz9qPLUG8GM8QPieC0Qp/3jZ938)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/)

```python
print map(lambda x:(ord(x)*'()',),'"\'rppp:1->o#13&;l2:6-&o@"\n"(f=_=>{q=(c=String.fromCharCode)(39);Q=c(34);s=c(92);console.log(q+[...`print map(lambda x:(ord(x)*${q}()${q},),${q+Q+s+q}rppp:1->o#13&;l2:6-&o@${Q+s}n${Q}(f=${f})()${Q+q}),${q}{({}<>)<>}<>${q}`].map(s=>c(43).repeat(s.charCodeAt())+c(46)).join()+q)})()"'),'{({}<>)<>}<>'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVDLasMwEPyV4Jpot0oEiUMgdmRa8gWmxyY0rh9Jii3Jsg8pQt/urksPPZReZliGmZ1d8zlctVqPo7E3Ncza3ECTt@9lPrvHoG0Jd3xkgGyBCxYcmTXGxKtlqh9W0Txp1vF2OddPwVEFUMs3mbpOQiFfBgq7iNrq9nDN7UGXFUK0wySTBUQbTHri3RqTQqteN5Vo9AU6/iqEOP/TI3SdB5yQ2hDxjPe88393Ch2pXhF5qha62uPkzcjwbfYOnN@nuE8Jp/l8EtPWXqYFbCIUtjJVPkAvip8TngdA5CRuEcWHvilA3uEUGzD6zu88No5f)

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7d09bgIxEMXxPqegY1eCGyCknCNKQYpIKBEFLcrZN5wgTfbDnvcTEqW9/zczz17bmI/75Xo7fn5fvqbpbdgP4/8/@8N42M3T1MKNtvkJQYUJs6@uF@@ogVyJSNdZIeuk38KdbZpaxfN6RbwEp@/b83l4l4/xR1Pr9CLn2kIqoSkVoxYvguGrZnqpALIjtQu3MGpADEsirgDlHQUqSIDV1S6Dxd08DMjQmC0GVGGZZLNo9xaVYsVj@YoTbBoQ9S/rqV1406XCSSJeAgakAQ4kPPtbFARpjky/iirWcFVjg5K38QkMYgKuMz5ATM@pBgRgeKzUUPSEqgFsYx9IvkultHMMMzftF@72IUS6uoGoclUu0onTBWaixhxdoAIlqUgAqDBh2hFovCM3X3YI6Tr5HlLL2RZOn@L5PLzbx7DGZnXI6pCchyhlWKRIJeha7XojBiU/xbSiRzIKMxneAjTBRHmeIgBKAK@@EooApY9mkFZ1SQHzXOUENFOA7jFcSAkwzZW8Ztp7FfCSRVHjD7kMylDFTtyAGBppaDomDYBAzdHdHaSAVEP/E7E@FwjMo7KXtRRFot@aWAHj5MbolMR2AseP82Zv@NnU@@4xPH5O5/F0fn6/TNN0fP0F)

## [Foo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Foo)

```python
"'rppp:1->o#13&;l2:6-&o@"
"(f=_=>{q=(c=String.fromCharCode)(39);Q=c(34);s=c(92);console.log(q+[...`print map(lambda x:(ord(x)*${q}()${q},),${q+Q+s+q}rppp:1->o#13&;l2:6-&o@${Q+s}n${Q}(f=${f})()${Q+q}),${q}{({}<>)<>}<>${q}`].map(s=>c(43).repeat(s.charCodeAt())+c(46)).join()+q)})()"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BasMwEETv@YrgmnS3SgSJQyB2JFryBabHUhpXttMU2ytLPgSEvt2VSo@9zLAMb3e2JZrn5NForfPtRtLDNlsV3S4/bFb0nCwSaMWHkG4UoMTrZG7DlbeG@vNXZc5UNwjZEYtSKMj2WNjgxx0WigZLXcM7usLI3jjnFx3QadlXGrqq/6yr5T0HMjXc8Sl1oweMusZ1MFYyy0b/f6XUhdQPwXyolrrWY2TLAPzC3oHzJ4knGTTOl3cer1ohFewz5KbRTTWB5ervhZcJEFkID4j8m24DIBsxrk0W8/wD)

This was actually the most annoying part of the code. Foo only supports string literals of 254 length for some reason, so I had to golf a bit and split up the Javascript from the 2D code to keep it short. The next person will probably have to split up the Javascript.